# Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe?

Tags: c++, c, qt, pipe, stdin

When I execute "`python`" from the terminal with no arguments it brings up the Python interactive shell.

When I execute "`cat | python`" from the terminal it doesn't launch the interactive mode. Somehow, without getting any input, it has detected that it is connected to a pipe.

How would I do a similar detection in C or C++ or Qt?

Comment: What you want is not to detect if stdin is a pipe, but if stdin/stdout is a terminal.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use `isatty`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
...    
if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
    printf( "stdin is a terminal\n" );
else
    printf( "stdin is a file or a pipe\n");
```

(On windows they're prefixed with underscores: `_isatty`, `_fileno`)

Comment: +1: stdin can be a pipe or redirected from a file. Better to check if it *is* interactive than to check if it is *not*.

Comment: On POSIX there is no `io.h` and for `isatty()` you need to include `unistd.h`.

Comment: Follow-up question: how to read out the piped contents in case stdin is not a tty? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16305971/96656

Comment: Note: You need to check stdout (STDOUT_FILENO) if you want to see whether your -output- is a tty or not, in case you want to suppress output if piped into `less`.

Answer (score 92):

### Summary

For many use cases the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) function [`isatty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) is all what it is needed to detect if stdin is connected to a terminal. A minimal example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
    puts("stdin is connected to a terminal");
  else
    puts("stdin is NOT connected to a terminal");
  return 0;
}
```

The following section compares different methods that can be used if different degrees of interactivity have to be tested.

### Methods in Detail

There are several methods to detect if a program is running interactively.
Following table shows an overview:

```
cmd\method             ctermid    open   isatty   fstat
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
./test                 /dev/tty   OK     YES      S_ISCHR
./test < test.cc       /dev/tty   OK     NO       S_ISREG
cat test.cc | ./test   /dev/tty   OK     NO       S_ISFIFO
echo ./test | at now   /dev/tty   FAIL   NO       S_ISREG
```

The results are from a Ubuntu Linux 11.04 system using the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  char tty[L_ctermid+1];
  ctermid(tty);
  printf("ID: %s\n", tty);
  int fd = open(tty, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) perror("Could not open terminal");
  else {
    printf("Opened terminal\n");
    struct termios term;
    int r = tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    if (r < 0) perror("Could not get attributes");
    else printf("Got attributes\n");
  }
  if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) printf("Is a terminal\n");
  else printf("Is not a terminal\n");
  struct stat stats;
  int r = fstat(fileno(stdin), &stats);
  if (r < 0) perror("fstat failed");
  else {
    if (S_ISCHR(stats.st_mode)) printf("S_ISCHR\n");
    else if (S_ISFIFO(stats.st_mode)) printf("S_ISFIFO\n");
    else if (S_ISREG(stats.st_mode)) printf("S_ISREG\n");
    else printf("unknown stat mode\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### Terminal device

If the interactive session needs certain capabilities, you can open the
terminal device and (temporarily) set terminal attributes you need
via `tcsetattr()`.

### Python Example

The [Python code that decides whether the interpreter runs interactively](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r271/Python/pythonrun.c) uses `isatty()`. The Function `PyRun_AnyFileExFlags()`

```
/* Parse input from a file and execute it */

int
PyRun_AnyFileExFlags(FILE *fp, const char *filename, int closeit,
                     PyCompilerFlags *flags)
{
    if (filename == NULL)
        filename = "???";
    if (Py_FdIsInteractive(fp, filename)) {
        int err = PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags(fp, filename, flags);
```

calls `Py_FdIsInteractive()`

```
/*
 * The file descriptor fd is considered ``interactive'' if either
 *   a) isatty(fd) is TRUE, or
 *   b) the -i flag was given, and the filename associated with
 *      the descriptor is NULL or "<stdin>" or "???".
 */
int
Py_FdIsInteractive(FILE *fp, const char *filename)
{
    if (isatty((int)fileno(fp)))
        return 1;
```

which calls `isatty()`.

### Conclusion

There are different degrees of interactivity. For checking if `stdin` is connected to a pipe/file or a real terminal `isatty()` is a natural method to do that.

Answer (score 8):

Probably they are checking the type of file that "stdin" is with fstat, something like this:

```
struct stat stats;
fstat(0, &stats);
if (S_ISCHR(stats.st_mode)) {
    // Looks like a tty, so we're in interactive mode.
} else if (S_ISFIFO(stats.st_mode)) {
    // Looks like a pipe, so we're in non-interactive mode.
}
```

Of course Python is open source, so you can just look at what they do and know for sure:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/Python-2.6.2.tar.bz2

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you can use GetFileType.

```
HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD type = GetFileType(hIn);
switch (type) {
case FILE_TYPE_CHAR: 
    // it's from a character device, almost certainly the console
case FILE_TYPE_DISK:
    // redirected from a file
case FILE_TYPE_PIPE:
    // piped from another program, a la "echo hello | myprog"
case FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
    // this shouldn't be happening...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call stat() or fstat() and see if S_IFIFO is set in st_mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `stat(0, &result)` and check for `!S_ISREG( result.st_mode )`. That's Posix, not C/C++, though.