# grep the adb logcat & write the output to a text file

Tags: android, file, text, grep, logcat

I want to grep the adb logcat and write the output to a text file.
If I just do:

```
./adb logcat > std.txt
```

it writes the entire log to the text file. If I do:

```
./adb logcat | grep ABC
```

it prints all lines containing ABC to my terminal. But now I wish to search for ABC & write only these lines to a text file.

This:

```
./adb logcat | grep ABC > std.txt
```

doesn't work.

What's the correct command?

Comment: I see the same problem. If I do `adb logcat | grep ABC` which produces among other things the string "XYZ", and then do a `adb logcat | grep ABC | grep XYZ` I get nothing. And I am absolute sure that output lines are produces which contains both "ABD" and "XYZ". How is this?

Comment: Which host OS, which grep? Works e.g. on my OS X with the supplied BSD grep

Comment: If you used eclipse you could use the special "save" button which does exactly this... :P

Comment: Hey, check my answer. It is a working solution! :)

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. It makes perfect sense, grep is buffering quite a lot of output from logcat, before it is returned. So whatever is after the grep in the pipe, will only receive output when some larger amount of data are ready to be emitted from grep. But by line buffering it in grep, grep will emit each line as it is filtered forward in the pipe.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think there is a problem with grep buffering. You can try something like this:

```
./adb logcat | grep --line-buffered ABC > std.txt
```

It should be the same problem for chained grep.

EDIT: A similar question can be found here: [Why no output is shown when using grep twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427483/tail-pipe-to-grep-pipe-to-another-grep-seems-to-be-a-pipe-too-far).

Comment: I'm not sure how I got by not knowing about "--line-buffered". This answer deserves a whole lot more upvotes!

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
This seems to work

```
 ./adb logcat |grep --line-buffered  ABC >a.txt
```

---

I can explain you what is happening heres. Hope someone can derive a solution from that.If you run the following command in terminal

```
cat |grep "ABC"
```

and start entering lines of text, you can see that grep immediately outputs any lines that contains.

```
 cat somefile.txt | grep "ABC"
```

will print all lines that contains 'ABC' to the terminal, as expected.

But if you run

```
cat |grep ABC >a.txt
```

and start entering text on the terminal, you can see that the file is not written until you enter an EOF character (Ctrl+ D) and make cat terminate.

But using --line-buffered gives output in the expected way

```
cat |grep --line-buffered  ABC >a.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

`./adb logcat | grep ABC | dd of=/home/levex/dump.txt`

**Explanation:** `./adb logcat` opens the logcat, and then it goes through a pipe to `grep ABC` which filters the lines to those containing `ABC`, and then again through a pipe to `dd of=/home/levex/dump.txt` to finally print it to a file.  `of=xxx` parameter sets the output file.

Answer (score 3):

Try `adb logcat | grep ABC | tee out`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
./adb logcat -s "ABC" > std.txt
```

Comment: Sorry UdayaLakmal & svnpenn, but this isn't working. It just writes these to lines to the file:                                                        --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main

Comment: Did you then run the application which produce "ABC" string, i tested this and following is my result for string "drriveAPI"

 adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
D/drriveAPI(27329): http://d.com/tag/abcdef/assign?
D/drriveAPI(27329): URLhttp://d.com/tag/abcdef/assign?
D/drriveAPI(27329): http://d.com/tag/abcdef/assign?
D/drriveAPI(27329): URLhttp://d.com/tag/abcdef/assign?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that maybe looking for all entries with word time, testapk1 and testapk2

```
adb logcat -v time testapk1 testapk2 *:S -d > adblogfilter.log
```

Answer (score 1):

[Save LogCat To A Text File](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file)

"To save LogCat to a text file open up a terminal window and type:
    adb logcat -d > logcat.txt"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
adb logcat -d -e "ABC" > std.txt
```