# Colorize log files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, colors

This is a follow-up on
[How to optimize script for colorizing log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356142/how-to-optimize-script-for-colorizing-log-files).

Here a my specifications:

- Line format is: `[Level][Date and time][Module] - [Interesting part]`
- Color `Level`, `Date and time`, and `Module` in BLACK for all lines
- Depending on `Level`:

  - `ERROR` - Color `Interesting part` in white on red
- Depending on `Module`:

  - `DataSourceImpl` - Use default color for `Interesting part`
  - `DbConnectionImpl` - Color `Interesting part` in white
  - `Handler` - Color `Interesting part` in magenta

That works very well with:

```
BEGIN {
    magenta = "\x1b[35m"; white = "\x1b[37m"; BLACK = "\x1b[30;1m"; onred = "\x1b[41m";
    reset  = "\x1b[0m"

    color["DataSourceImpl"] = reset
    color["DbConnectionImpl"] = white
    color["Handler"] = magenta
}

match($0, /\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\] - \[(.*)\]/, a) {
    if (a[1] == "ERROR" || a[1] == "WARN ")
    {
        print BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" reset white onred a[4] reset BLACK "]" reset
        next
    }
    else if (a[3] == "DataSourceImpl" || a[3] == "DbConnectionImpl" || a[3] == "Handler")
        $0 = BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" reset color[a[3]] a[4] reset BLACK "]" reset
    else
        $0 = BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" a[4] "]" reset
}

// {print $0}
```

On a 45 MB log file:

- `cat server.log | colorlog` takes 15.277 seconds
- `cat server.log` takes 14.007

so, it even is fast enough!  Almost no visible difference...

Now, extra specifications:

- Highlight SQL constructs

  - `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE` in yellow
  - `INSERT INTO ..` in green
  - `DELETE FROM ..` in red
    where table names should be higlighted in "bold" colors.

  NOTE -- `SELECT` keywords used in `INSERT TO` constructs (instead of `VALUES`)
  can be highlighted in yellow as well. No exception.
- Highlight strings (between quotes) in cyan.

Updated script:

```
BEGIN {
    magenta = "\x1b[35m"; white = "\x1b[37m"; BLACK = "\x1b[30;1m"; onred = "\x1b[41m";
    yellow="\x1b[33m"; YELLOW="\x1b[33;1m"; cyan="\x1b[36m"
    reset  = "\x1b[0m"

    color["DataSourceImpl"] = reset
    color["DbConnectionImpl"] = white
    color["Handler"] = magenta
}

match($0, /\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\] - \[(.*)\]/, a) {
    if (a[1] == "ERROR" || a[1] == "WARN ")
    {
        print BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" reset white onred a[4] reset BLACK "]" reset
        next
    }
    else if (a[3] == "DataSourceImpl" || a[3] == "DbConnectionImpl" || a[3] == "Handler")
        $0 = BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" reset color[a[3]] a[4] reset BLACK "]" reset
    else
        $0 = BLACK "[" a[1] "][" a[2] "][" a[3] "] - [" a[4] "]" reset
}

match($0, /(.*)(SELECT|select)(.*)((FROM|from) ([^ )]*))([^\]]*)(WHERE|where)(.*)/, a) {
    $0 = a[1] yellow a[2] reset a[3] yellow a[5] reset " " YELLOW a[6] reset yellow a[7] yellow a[8] reset a[9]
}

// { gsub(/'[^']*'/, cyan "&" reset); }

// {print $0}
```

This incomplete script already leads to the following problems:

1. Only one `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE` construct is higlighted per line -- and
   I don't see how to avoid this (unlike what I did for highlighting the strings
   between quotes.
2. Execution time explodes: 4 minutes 44 seconds!!!
3. Colors are not surimposed on my initial choices: after `SELECT`, the colum
   names are colored with the default foreground color, not anymore in white
   (when module was `DbConnectionImpl`).  That's because of the "reset" color;
   but I don't see how to do to add color, but preserving what I had before.

Any tip on what direction to take to solve these problems?

Comment: The is a tool called [colortail](https://manned.org/colortail/76583027)

Comment: Sample input (completely representative, on one screen page) available at: http://codepaste.net/3r7hce.

Comment: Current output (demo'ing the above mentioned problems) available at: http://screencast.com/t/EXZEhz2Ta.

Comment: Don't just describe an input format and don't assume we're going to go looking at links - post concise, testable sample input, truly representative and expected output **in your question**. If it's too big to include in your question then it's too big to expect us to read. Keep it concise.