# BASH - tr newlines of grep result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, tr

I have a `grep -o '100%'` piped after a `wget`, so I'm only notified that `wget` completed the download, without useless information on screen. But each `100%` is printed on a new line, and I don't like this flood! So, is there a way to `tr` the newlines into spaces, by piping `tr` after `grep`? All I got was no result, each time I tried...

Answer (score 2):

You would have gotten output eventually, but all in one go. This is due to buffering.

GNU `grep` has a `--line-buffered` to avoid output buffering. `tr` does input buffering with no apparent way to turn it off, so you can use `awk` instead:

```
wget -r -l 1 http://stackoverflow.com/ 2>&1 |
    grep --line-buffered -o '100%' | awk '{printf("%s ", $0);}'
100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%
```

Comment: "You would have gotten output eventually, but all in one go." True, I confirmed now. I have not waited long because there were a lot of files to download, and it's very annoying to look at a screen that has no information about what is happening!

Comment: Are you sure that `--line-buffered` _disables_ buffering? Both `man` and `info` says otherwise: "Use line buffering on output.". By the way, using it or not gives the same result: all `100%` only at the end.

Comment: Are you trying the command as provided here or did you just add `--line-buffered` to your existing command?

Comment: I followed your instructions, but only after the `wget`. So I maintained my `wget` (not recursive, input from file) and added what you suggested. Anyway, now I tested exactly what you suggested, except without the line break between `wget` and `grep`, and there was no `100%` until I aborted the process for taking too long without any output, and noticing that the download stopped at 18 items on the folder.

Comment: That's pretty strange and I can't reproduce it. How about if you use `stdbuf -oL wget ... `?

Comment: Indeed, it's strange. As even with you `stdbuf`suggestion it still cannot work, I must ask: on which version of `wget` your solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

It's buffering, see [Why no output is shown when using grep twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5427483/1745001). Just use awk:

```
$ wget -r -l 1 https://stackoverflow.com/ 2>&1 | awk 'match($0,/100%/){printf "%s ", substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%
```

or probably more useful:

```
$ wget -r -l 1 https://stackoverflow.com/ 2>&1 | awk '/100%/{printf "."}'
...........
```

Comment: I copied and executed the commands as they were written by you. Both downloaded 18 items, gave no output, and needed to be canceled (CTRL+C) to stop executing. I think, with this repeating to more than 1 solution of more than 1 replier, that other things needs to be checked. On which version of `wget` your solution worked?

Comment: GNU Wget 1.16.3 built on cygwin.

Comment: I was on 1.17.1, so I updated to 1.18 and tried again. Same non-results... So it's not `wget` the culprit. Maybe `awk`? Here it's being caled mawk by man and info.

Comment: Only suggestion I have left is to install gawk, sorry.