# Tail -f with external sed

Tags: shell, sed, tail

I have a tail that makes a site in an external file:

```
tail -f LOG.TXT | grep ';HI(<[0-9][0-9]><[0-9]>' | sed -u -f seds.dat |awk '{ print $1, $2, $5 = "HELLO =", $6, $7, $8, $9 } ' |grep -v '>'
```

I believe that the tail does not work because the delay to perform sed in seds.dat

Using CAT it takes a while but returns the information.

I would like to make it update the rows with tail?

Comment: so you say `tail | grep | sed | awk | grep`. Uhms, are you aware that this can probably squeezed into a single `awk` command?

Comment: could you provide sample LOG.TXT;

Comment: The log.txt is another machine mount point, I think talves this is one of the reasons.

Comment: It's buffering, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427483/why-no-output-is-shown-when-using-grep-twice. If you post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output I expect someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `tail -f LOG.TXT` means that the tail will not finish when it reaches the end of file. It will wait for more data to be written to LOG.TXT. I imagine this is why you think it is not working.