# Reading piped output line by line python

Tags: python, pipe

I'm using popen to run a subprocess in python. I need to read each line the subprocess outputs as it is being outputted, rather then getting everything once the process terminates. I've tried everything I could find on Google with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544050/force-another-programs-standard-output-to-be-unbuffered-using-python

Answer (score 1):

The [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) documentation describes the available arguments to its call.

You want to set the `bufsize` argument to `1` (line-buffered input/output).