# Is there a way to set up a Linux pipe to non-buffering or line-buffering?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, flush

My program is controlling an external application on Linux, passing in input commands via a pipe to the external applications stdin, and reading output result via a pipe from the external applications stdout.

The problem is that writes to pipes are buffered by block, and not by line, and therefore delays occur before my app receives data output by the external application. The external application cannot be altered to add explicit fflush() calls.

When I set the external application to */bin/cat -n* (it echoes back the input, with line numbers added), it works correctly, it seems, *cat* flushes after each line. The only way to force the external application to flush, is sending *exit* command to it; as it receives the command, it flushes, and all the answers appears on the stdout, just before exiting.

I'm pretty sure, that Unix pipes are appropiate solution for that kind of interprocess communication (pseudo server-client), but maybe I'm wrong.

*(I've just copied some text from a similar question: [Force another program's standard output to be unbuffered using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544050/force-another-programs-standard-output-to-be-unbuffered-using-python))*

Comment: Here's another excellent linux buffering discussion:  
    http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a pipe. Use a pty instead. Pty's (pseudo-ttys) have the benefit of being line buffered if you want it, which provides you with simple framing for your data stream.

Comment: It is not the pty that decides about the buffering. It is the application (or library used by it) which contains the output buffer and changes the output buffering to line-buffering when the output goes to a (pseudo)terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Using a PTY may be an overkill for the problem at hand (although it *will* work).

If the "target application" (the Delphi command-line utility) is dynamically linked, a possibly much simpler solution is to interpose (via `LD_PRELOAD`) a small library into the application. That library simply needs to implement `isatty`, and answer `true` (return 1) regardless of whether the output is going to a pipe or a terminal. You may wish to do that for all file descriptors, or just for `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Most UNIX implementations will call `isatty` to decide whether to do full buffering or line buffering for a given file descriptor.

Hmm, glibc doesn't. It calls `__fxstat`, and then only calls `isatty` if the status indicates that `fd` is going to a character device. So you'll need to interpose both `__fxstat` and `isatty`. More on library interposition [here](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html).

Comment: Here's a good example for using pty http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html#Inter-process_communication_through_a

Answer (score 1):

By default standard input and standard output are fully buffered unless they are connected to an interactive device in which cases they are line buffered [1]. Pipes are non-interactive devices. PTYs *are* interactive devices. "Fully buffered" means "use a chunk of memory of a certain size".

I'm sure you want line buffering. Therefore using a master/slave PTY instead of pipes should bring the controlled application into the right buffering mode automatically.

[1] see "stdin(3)" and "setbuf(3)" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Why calling `fflush` suitably (on the write side) don't work for you?

You can use [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) (or other syscalls like `ppoll`, `pselect`, `select`) to check availability of input on the read side.

If the external application is using `<stdio.h>` without calling `fflush` appropriately (perhaps by `setbuf` making it happen on newlines ....), data would remain inside its `FILE*` buffer without even being sent (with a `write` syscall) to the pipe!

An application can detect if its output is a terminal with e.g. [isatty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty). But it should ensure that flushing happens...

As Michael Dillon suggested, using [pty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)-s is probably the best. But it is hard (I forgot the gory details).

Comment: Simple answer: it's not my program. (Difficult answer: we're trying to port a Delphi stuff to Linux; the external program is a Delphi command-line util running with Wine. I'm not sure what a Delphi flush() does, whether will it work. We will try it, but even it works, the problem is worth to solve.)

Comment: But if the application is not flushing, then it is buggy to the point of being unusable...

Comment: The application works great in the shell. Hm, I've an idea now.