# Fail to read from `tail -F` via `stdin`

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a growing csv file with the following script `parse.py`:

```
import csv
import sys

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

The corresponding command line is `tail -F log | python parse.py`.

Then I try to append some rows to `log` with `echo "something" >> log`.

But `parse.py` print nothing.

What's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that what you're adding to the log file is being buffered and not passed to the other commands in the pipeline.

For more information, please have a look at [how big is the pipe buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11946/12596).

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544050/force-another-programs-standard-output-to-be-unbuffered-using-python