# Detecting when a child process is waiting for input

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pty, unbuffered-output

I'm writing a Python program for running user-uploaded arbitrary (and thus, at the worst case, unsafe, erroneous and crashing) code on a Linux server. The security questions aside, my objective is to determine, if the code (that might be in any language, compiled or interpreted) writes the correct things to `stdout`, `stderr` and other files on given input fed into the program's `stdin`. After this, I need to display the results to the user.

## The current solution

Currently, my solution is to spawn the child process using `subprocess.Popen(...)` with file handles for the `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin`. The file behind the `stdin` handle contains the inputs that the program reads during operation, and after the program has terminated, the `stdout` and `stderr` files are read and checked for correctness.

### The problem

This approach works otherwise perfectly, but when I display the results, I can't combine the given inputs and outputs so that the inputs would appear in the same places as they would when running the program from a terminal. I.e. for a program like

```py
print "Hello."
name = raw_input("Type your name: ")
print "Nice to meet you, %s!" % (name)
```

the contents of the file containing the program's `stdout` would, after running, be:

```
Hello.
Type your name: 
Nice to meet you, Anonymous!
```

given that the contents the file containing the `stdin` were `Anonymous<LF>`. So, in short, for the given example code (and, equivalently, for *any* other code) I want to achieve a result like:

```
Hello.
Type your name: Anonymous
Nice to meet you, Anonymous!
```

Thus, the problem is to detect when the program is waiting for input.

## Tried methods

I've tried the following methods for solving the problem:

### [Popen.communicate(...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

This allows the parent process to separately send data along a [pipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE), but can only be called once, and is therefore not suitable for programs with multiple outputs and inputs - just as can be inferred from the documentation.

### Directly reading from [Popen.stdout](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) and [Popen.stderr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) and writing to [Popen.stdin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)

The documentation warns against this, and the `Popen.stdout`s [`.read()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) and [`.readline()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) calls seem to block infinitely when the programs starts to wait for input.

### Using [`select.select(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) to see if the file handles are ready for I/O

This doesn't seem to improve anything. Apparently the pipes are always ready for reading or writing, so `select.select(...)` doesn't help much here.

### Using a different thread for non-blocking reading

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/2096560), I have tried creating a separate [Thread()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) that stores results from reading from the `stdout` into a [Queue()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects). The output lines before a line demanding user input are displayed nicely, but the line on which the program starts to wait for user input (`"Type your name: "` in the example above) never gets read.

### Using a [PTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) slave as the child process' file handles

As directed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547764/2096560), I've tried [`pty.openpty()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html#pty.openpty) to create a pseudo terminal with master and slave file descriptors. After that, I've given the slave file descriptor as an argument for the `subprocess.Popen(...)` call's `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` parameters. Reading through the master file descriptor opened with [`os.fdopen(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen) yields the same result as using a different thread: the line demanding input doesn't get read.

**Edit:** Using @Antti Haapala's example of `pty.fork()` for child process creation instead of `subprocess.Popen(...)` seems to allow me also read the output created by `raw_input(...)`.

### Using [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect)

I've also tried the `read()`, `read_nonblocking()` and `readline()` methods (documented [here](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html)) of a process spawned with pexpect, but the best result, which I got with `read_nonblocking()`, <s>is the same as before: the line with outputs before wanting the user to enter something doesn't get read.</s> is the same as with a PTY created with `pty.fork()`: the line demanding input *does* get read.

**Edit:** By using `sys.stdout.write(...)` and `sys.stdout.flush()` instead of `print`ing in my *master* program, which creates the child, seemed to fix the prompt line not getting displayed - it actually got read in both cases, though.

### Others

I've also tried [`select.poll(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll), but it seemed that the pipe or PTY master file descriptors are always ready for writing.

## Notes

### Other solutions

- What also crossed my mind is to try feeding the input when some time has passed without new output having been generated. This, however, is risky, because there's no way to know if the program is just in the middle of doing a heavy calculation.
- As @Antti Haapala mentioned in his answer, the `read()` system call wrapper from glibc could be replaced to communicate the inputs to the master program. However, this doesn't work with statically linked or assembly programs. (Although, now that I think of it, any such calls could be intercepted from the source code and replaced with the patched version of `read()` - could be painstaking to implement still.)
- Modifying the Linux kernel code to communicate the `read()` syscalls to the program is probably insane...

### PTYs

I think the PTY is the way to go, since it fakes a terminal and interactive programs are run on terminals everywhere. The question is, how?

Comment: +1 very well presented question. I do think that PTY is the correct approach because the typed user input appears neither on the stdin or stdout, it is a function of tty/pty echoing. That said, I've not used the `pty` module, so can't give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you noticed that raw_input writes the prompt string into stderr if stdout is terminal (isatty); if stdout is not a terminal, then the prompt too is written to stdout, but stdout will be in fully buffered mode.

**With stdout on a tty**

```
write(1, "Hello.\n", 7)                  = 7
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "Type your name: ", 16)         = 16
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb114059000
read(0, "abc\n", 1024)                   = 4
write(1, "Nice to meet you, abc!\n", 23) = 23
```

**With stdout not on a tty**

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff8d9d3410) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
# oops, python noticed that stdout is NOTTY.
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f29895f0000
read(0, "abc\n", 1024)                     = 4
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f29891c4bd0}, {0x451f62, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f29891c4bd0}, 8) = 0
write(1, "Hello.\nType your name: Nice to m"..., 46) = 46
# squeeze all output at the same time into stdout... pfft.
```

Thus all writes are squeezed into stdout all at the same time; and what is worse, after the input is read.

The real solution is thus to use the pty. However you are doing it wrong. For the pty to work, you must use the pty.fork() command, not subprocess. (This will be very tricky). I have some working code that goes like this:

```
import os
import tty
import pty

program = "python"

# command name in argv[0]
argv = [ "python", "foo.py" ]

pid, master_fd = pty.fork()

# we are in the child process
if pid == pty.CHILD:
    # execute the program
    os.execlp(program, *argv)

# else we are still in the parent, and pty.fork returned the pid of 
# the child. Now you can read, write in master_fd, or use select:
# rfds, wfds, xfds = select.select([master_fd], [], [], timeout)
```

Notice that depending on the terminal mode set by the child program there might be different kinds of linefeeds coming out, etc.

Now about the "waiting for input" problem, that cannot be really helped as one can always write to a pseudoterminal; the characters will be put to wait in the buffer. Likewise, a pipe always allows one to write up to 4K or 32K or some other implementation defined amount, before blocking. One ugly way is to strace the program and notice whenever it enters the read system call, with fd = 0; the other would be to make a C module with a replacement "read()" system call and link it in before glibc for the dynamic linker (fails if the executable is statically linked or uses system calls directly with assembler...), and then would signal python whenever the read(0, ...) system call is executed. All in all, probably not worth the trouble exactly.

Comment: Would you happen to know whether this "input waiting detection" is natively possible on some other platform than Linux - some BSD for example? Or if there are existing patches to Linux kernel that would allow such interception out-of-the-box?

Comment: @miikkas: [gdb may allow you to replace a syscall](http://erenyagdiran.github.io/I-was-just-asked-to-crack-a-program-Part-1/). `pexpect` should work on BSD too. You could [use `pty.spawn()`  on Linux in simple cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25923901/4279)

Comment: Any solution for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Pexpect worked for me

In your case here's what you could do :

```
import pexpect
import time

# Start the other program
child = pexpect.spawn("python your_program.py", encoding='utf-8', timeout=None)

while True:
    #pexpect will "wait" until this line is displayed in the child program
    #so if you know what will be the last line before the input request,
    #then let him "expect" that
    child.expect("Type your name: ")

    #This prints what's "before" the thing you expected
    print(child.before)

    #Now you can collect the input from your user
    user_input = input("Type your name: ")

    #And send it down
    child.sendline(user_input)

    #The loop doesn't stop here, we can wait for the next time the child program asks the user "Type your name: " and do it as many times as we want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to detect when the child process is waiting for an input, you can use the linux `script` command. From the man page for script:

> The **script** utility makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.

You can use it like this if you were using it on a terminal:

```
$ script -q <outputfile> <command>
```

So in Python you can try giving this command to the `Popen` routine instead of just `<command>`.

Edit:
I made the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("i + 1 = %d\n", i+1);
}
```

and then ran it as follows:

```
$ echo 9 > infile
$ script -q output ./a.out < infile
$ cat output
9
i + 1 = 10
```

So I think it can be done in Python this way instead of using the `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` flags of `Popen`.

Comment: `script` doesn't seem to solve the main problem of timing the automatically fed inputs to their corresponding prompts in the stdout for the code that is being tested.

Comment: I think you can do it in a shell script, and I edited my answer to show this. However I am unsure whether you can port this as is to Python.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the results in the example; the output only contains the date when the script was started if the `./a.out < infile` part is enclosed in quotes (without quotes it contains nothing). Does your example work even when the program is more complex, i.e. there are `printf()`s before `scanf()`s and/or multiple different `scanf()`s?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem. If you enclose the `./a.out < infile` in quotes, that part does not get interpreted as a command, so I would not expect any output. The date part can be suppressed by passing the `-q` option. Can you tell me what shell and system you are using?