# Last unbuffered line can't be read

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pty

I'm trying to read the last line from a command like 'apt-get download firefox'. Normally the output will be like

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main firefox amd64 32.0+build1-0ubuntu2 [34.9 MB]
2% [1 firefox 646 kB/34.9 MB 2%]
```

with the last line continuously updating (it is not writing a newline until it reaches 100%). My goal is now to read the progress in realtime. Here is my current example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u
# coding=utf-8

import subprocess, sys

pipe = subprocess.Popen(['apt-get', 'download', 'firefox'], 0, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    content = pipe.stdout.read(1).decode()
    if content == '':
        break
    sys.stdout.write(content)
    sys.stdout.flush()
pipe.wait()
```

I have disabled the output buffering for the subprocess call and also for binary output for the Python process (with the -u argument). But I'm only getting the first line but not the progress of the second line. Does somebody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: you need either threads or async.io to read *both* streams concurrently . See [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279).

Comment: Do you need to capture `Get:1 http://..` line (stdout?) or is it enough if you get only the last (progress) line (stderr?)?

Comment: Things to check: 1. does `apt-get` writes only to stdout/stderr or can it [write to the terminal directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20980965/4279)? 2. Does it [use the block-buffering if the stdout is a pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)? 3. Does it show the progress line if stderr is redirected to a pipe?

Comment: Is it acceptable to merge stdout/stderr in you case (or just ignore the stderr)?

Comment: The output comes normally from stdout. Catching stderr is just for future development and removing it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stdout of `apt-get` is redirected to a pipe e.g.,

```
$ apt-get download firefox | cat
```

then it doesn't report progress (the last line e.g., `2% [1 firefox 646 kB/34.9 MB 2%]` will **not** be in the output). `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` naturally creates a pipe; therefore `apt-get` doesn't print the download progress in your case.

If you want both to capture `apt-get` output and to see it on the screen in real-time with the last line (progress report) present then you could [use `pexpect` module to trick the child process into thinking that it runs in a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279):

```
import sys
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

output, exitstatus = pexpect.runu('apt-get download firefox',
                                  logfile=sys.stdout,
                                  withexitstatus=1)
```

You could do the same using only stdlib `pty` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import pty

output = []
def read(fd):
    data = os.read(fd, 1024)
    output.append(data)
    return data
status = pty.spawn(['apt-get', 'download', 'firefox'], read)
```

[@eryksun on Python Issue tracker suggested](http://bugs.python.org/issue22443#msg227147) `apt-get`'s `--quiet` option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shlex
from io import TextIOWrapper
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = []
with Popen(shlex.split("apt-get --quiet=0 download firefox"),
           stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1) as p:
    # recognize '\r' as newline but don't convert it to '\n'
    for line in TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, newline=''):
        print(line, end='', flush=True) # print to terminal
        output.append(line) # save for later
print(p.returncode)
```