# Can't get stdout data python

Tags: python, subprocess, output, stdout

I'm trying to get the output of a command's STDOUT with the HandBrakeCLI program when encoding a video. I can't seem to get python to handle its output on the standard output stream. I've tried the following codes:

```
import subprocess
import sys

encode = subprocess.check_output("HandBrakeCLI -i video.mkv -o out.mp4", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
print(encode)
```

This printed nothing as well as this which I also tried:

```
import subprocess
import sys

encode = subprocess.Popen("HandBrakeCLI -i video.mkv -o out.mp4", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(encode.stdout.read())
```

As stated before, both will result in no output. This application is the type that will update text on a single line in bash as it's encoding. I'm not sure if that type of data stream creates a problem with python or not.

Comment: have you tried typing you cmd in shell, and does it have return?

Comment: unrelated: the second code example should use `out, err = encode.communicate()` to avoid the possibility of deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `HandBrakeCLI` changes its output depending on whether it prints to a terminal. Either specify a command-line flag to force the necessary output or you could trick it by providing a pseudo-tty (if your system supports it) using `pexpect` or `pty` module directly.

Code examples on how to get output from a subprocess using `pexpect`, `pty` modules:

- [Last unbuffered line can't be read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945031/4279)
- [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)