# Python subprocess popen pipe

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, python-2.4

I am trying to issue a command in python and read the input and parse it back. This is the command i am trying to issue (example when running on the command line)

```
-bash-3.2$ echo "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0.1 -p 7000
PASSTHRU TST,1234
udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response
-bash-3.2$
```

I am trying to use python subprocess

```
            vsh_command = ' "passthru ' + cmd + '" | ./vsh -a ' + ip_address + ' -p ' + port
            print vsh_command
            new_command = ['echo', vsh_command]
            print new_command
            proc = subprocess.Popen(new_command,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    shell=True)
            print '1'
            out_2, err = proc.communicate()
            print out_2
            print '2'
            rcv = out_2.splitlines()
            print '3'
            for r in rcv:
                    print '     ' + r
            print '4'
```

`

```
 "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0.1 -p 7000
['echo', ' "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0.1 -p 7000']
1


2
3

4
```

Is a | command not possible with subprocess? if so is there another way that i can run this shell command and get the input?

UPDATE: (With single string for shell=true command)

```
`vsh_command = 'echo "passthru ' + cmd + '" | ./vsh -a ' + ip_address + ' -p ' + port
            print vsh_command
            proc = subprocess.Popen(vsh_command,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    shell=True)
            print '1'
            out_2, err = proc.communicate()
            print out_2
            print '2'
            rcv = out_2.splitlines()
            print '3'
            for r in rcv:
                    print '     ' + r
            print '4'
```

`

Run (python script)

```
echo "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0.1 -p 7000
1
PASSTHRU TST,1234

2
3
     PASSTHRU TST,1234
4
SUCCESS
```

Still not quite what im looking for, looks like its just doing the echo command not the pipe

EDIT #2

```
            p = Popen(["./vsh", "-a", ip_address, "-p", str(port)],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
            out, err =  p.communicate("passthru TST,1234")
            print '----------'
            print out
```

Output:

```
-bash-3.2$ python mfd_ascii_test.py
udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response
----------
PASSTHRU TST,1234

-bash-3.2$
```

out is the result of the echo, not the 'udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response'

Comment: You need to pass a single string with shell=True to pipe or use two processes piping the stdout of the first to the stdin of the second

Comment: Updated per your comment to try one single string

Comment: *"Still not quite what im looking for"* -- what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: This is the result i get when i run on the command line: 
udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response. But it looks like i just get the results of the eqcho

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham vsh is a script to send udp packets that we use

Comment: unrelated: to avoid doubling newlines, use `print s,` (note: comma) -- it is [softspace](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html#l2h-256) hack. btw, do you want both to capture stdout/stderr as strings *and* to print them? If all you want is to print them then I don't understand why do you need to capture them, just remove `stdout=PIPE` and the output will appear on the screen.

Comment: I want to parse the output of the script in the python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a string as an input to a subprocess and to capture its output, you could use [`Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node239.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(["./vsh", "-a", ip_address, "-p", str(port)],
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.communicate("passthru " + cmd)[0]
```

`stderr=STDOUT` merges stderr into stdout.

Set `stdout=PIPE` to capture stdout, set `stderr=PIPE` to capture stderr; otherwise `communicate()` returns `None` for the corresponding pipes. If the process may write outside stdout, stderr then [use `pexpect` or `pty` + `select` modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279). Here's [`pexpect.runu()` and `pty.spawn()` code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945031/4279).

Comment: running python 2.4, doesn't like str object has no attribute format

Comment: How do i get the output?                 `out, err =  p.communicate("passthru IDN?,1234")
                print '----------'
                print out`
`-bash-3.2$ python mfd_ascii_test.py
PASSTHRU IDN?,1234
udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response
----------
None
`

Comment: @georges: include *minimal* code example and show its result in the question (to enable proper formatting). Set `stdout=PIPE` to capture stdout, set `stderr=PIPE` to capture stderr. If the process may write outside stdout, stderr then [use pexpect or pty modules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Comment: @georges: what about `stderr=PIPE`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pipe the output from one to the other, you can pipe the stdout from one process to the stdin of another:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p1 = Popen(["echo", "passthru TST,1234"],stdout=PIPE)

p2 = Popen(["./vsh", "-a", "127.0.0.1", "-p", "7000"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
out, err = p2.communicate()
```

If you wanted to use the pipe character, you would need to set shell=True and pass a single string:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output('echo "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0.1 -p 7000',shell=True)
```

Comment: -bash-3.2$ echo "passthru TST,1234" | ./vsh -a 127.0.0;1 -p 7000
udp_send_command: timed out waiting for response...................

`-bash-3.2$ python mfd_ascii_test.py
----
,`

and the code

    `p1 = Popen(["echo", "passthru TST,1234"],stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(["./vsh", "-a", "127.0.0.1", "-p", "7000"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)p1.stdout.close()
                out, err = p2.communicate()
                print '----'
                print out`

Comment: should I do `p2.stdout.close()` after calling `p2.communicate()`? @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @alper, not needed. As per the docs you `Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.` `stdout` and `stderr` are both closed regardless in `communicate`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use directly a string command with `subprocess.check_output` if you set `shell=True` it's easier this way (python 2.7).

```
output = subprocess.check_output(" ".join(new_command), shell=True)
```

Or you can use `subprocess.Popen` (python < 2.7).

```
output, err = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(new_command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

Comment: in this case use `output, err = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(new_command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()` it'll get the job done.