# In Linux, how to get the terminal output in real time in python before the end process?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, terminal

How do I catch the output of command `dcfldd` that goes to the terminal in Linux and show output in real time in python ?

This video shows the numbers in the same line,  how do I get this in real time before end process?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmfoBDbuGUo&feature=youtu.be&t=5m57s

Comment: related: [Last unbuffered line can't be read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25923901/4279)

Comment: You might find your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6414278/5134525

Comment: not work any answer to get output of command 'dcfldd'

Comment: *"not work"* is not very informative: [create a minimal but complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that shows the issue and add it to the answer (click [edit] under the question).