# Get output colored text with Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, popen

I'm using popen to make a plugin, this plugin used a external program who shows some colored text in the output.

The output is something like this:

```
avr-g++ -o .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial.o -c -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO=10607 -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduinoVariant .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial.cpp    
avr-g++ -o .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial0.o -c -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO=10607 -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduinoVariant .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial0.cpp
=============================================
Path\file.cpp: in function 'void loop()':
Path\file.cpp:23:2 error: expected ';' before '}' token
}
^
=============================================
```

All inside "=" is in red and yellow.

When I run the command in the command console, I can see the full output, but when I use Popen I only can get the uncolored text

This is how I'm using Popen

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=self.cwd, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()

stdout = output[0]
stderr = output[1]

print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

I would like to get the text even if it's not  colored, the important is to get the full log.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Kindly vote up my answer if it helped to fix  your problem. :)

Comment: Done! thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to get all that message because a part of your command output is not regular output, it is considered as Error (or log or debug messages)

Now you can either add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to your Popen's parameters, which will put all the errors in your `stderr` variable:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=self.cwd, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()

stdout = output[0]
stderr = output[1]

print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

OR if you want to have all the errors and output just like what you see in the console, add `2>&1` at the end of your command. something like:

```
avr-g++ -o .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial.o -c -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO=10607 -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino -I.pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduinoVariant .pioenvs\uno\FrameworkArduino\HardwareSerial.cpp 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahman, the last suggestion solved my problem. Do you have a link to read something about that solution, or can you explain me the meaning of `2>&1`?

Comment: @GEPD Here's the link that I read before answering you http://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/811922

Comment: @GEPD: And to see how to preserve the color codes take a look at  `-fdiagnostics-color[=WHEN]` in the [avr-g++ man page](https://manned.org/avr-g++).

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring I'll look now, I'm not directly working with avr-g++ but it is good to know this extra information.

Answer (score 3):

> When I run the command in the command console, I can see the full output, but when I use Popen I only can get the uncolored text

There could be *two* issues:

1. the colored text happens to be produced on stderr, not stdout. To capture stderr, set `stderr=PIPE`, [as @Rahman suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625257/4279)
2. `avr-g++` command may disable colors if it detects that the output is not a tty e.g., if it is redirected to a pipe like in your case. To enable colors, pass the command-line option `-fdiagnostics-color=always` [as @PM 2Ring suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624751/get-output-colored-text-with-popen#comment56999691_34625257).

   Or (less portable but it may work with more commands) provide a pseudo-tty to hoodwink the `avr-g++` command into thinking that it runs interactively (and therefore it should enable colors). You could do it using [`pty.spawn()`, `pexpect` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945031/4279):

   ```
   import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

   output, exitstatus = pexpect.runu(command, withexitstatus=1)
   ```

   or (more low-level) using [`pty.openpty()` + `subprocess` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279).