# Killing subprocess after first line

Tags: subprocess, python-3.4

I am executing program which connects to external server from python.
If user is not authenticated, the program asks for username and password.

Here is how subprogram output looks:

```
Authentication Required

Enter authorization information for "Web API"

<username_prompt_here>
<password_prompt_here>
```

I want to kill subprocess right after 'Authentication Required' is printed, but the problem is, that my code works wrong - subprocess is asking for credentials and after user provides it, the subprocess is killed.

Here is my code:

```
with subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        if 'Authentication Required' in line:
            print('No authentication')
            process.kill()
        print(line)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? or is it complete? I don't see where you are prompting user for username and password.

Comment: I'm not prompting - the subprogram does it (look at attatched output).

Comment: and you want to kill the process immediatly after Authentication Required line?

Comment: does it actually wait for the user to enter username and password beforing exiting the sub routine?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to let subprogram ask for password, in current situation is asking for it, and after that is killed.

Comment: And - not always I want to kill program after first line. Only if first line is 'Authentication required'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103923/discussion-between-usama-zafar-and-djent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your code is ok (if you want to kill the subprocess after `'Authentication Required'` line regardless its position) if the child process flushes its stdout buffer in time.  See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

The observed behavior indicates that the child uses a block-buffering mode and therefore your parent script sees the `'Authentication Required'` line too late or that killing the shell with `process.kill()` doesn't kill its descendants (processes created by the command).

To workaround it:

- See whether you could pass a command-line argument such as `--line-buffered` (accepted by `grep`), to force a line-buffered mode
- Or see whether `stdbuf`, `unbuffer`, `script` utilities work in your case
- Or provide a pseudo-tty to hoodwink the process into thinking that it runs in a terminal directly — it may also force the line-buffered mode.

See code examples in:

- [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198/4279)
- [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)
- [Last unbuffered line can't be read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923901/4279)

---

> And - not always I want to kill program after first line. Only if first line is 'Authentication required'

Assuming the block-buffering issue is fixed, to kill the child process if the first line contains `Authentication Required`:

```
with Popen(shlex.split(command), 
           stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    first_line = next(process.stdout)
    if 'Authentication Required' in first_line:
        process.kill()
    else: # whatever
        print(first_line, end='')
        for line in process.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
```

If `shell=True` is necessary in your case then see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).