# Python subprocess PIPE blocking

Tags: python, process, pipe, subprocess, stdout

The subprocess will output several characters, and I want to send some response via stdin. The length of the output is predictable, so I wrote code like this:

```
p = Popen("myproc", shell = True, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
p.stdout.read(1)
```

However, `p.stdout.read(1)` doesn't return even if the process had already output more than a character. How can I make it stop blocking after reading a byte sequence of the expected length?

Comment: If you can, use select and poll. Also try using `flush()`.

Comment: This can be difficult to get right. You might be better off using [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org) for reading/writing pipes in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myproc` may use a block-buffering mode when the standard output is redirected i.e., your parent Python won't see anything until the corresponding buffer in the child is flushed. See [several ways to workaround it in this answer (and follow the corresponding links there)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35507693/4279).