# Check_output returning immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.4

I am running a command with python3.4 subprocess. The command has 2 options, one standard and one interactive. The problem is that if I run it in the standard mode check_process returns immediately. I have also checked running it with `subprocess.call` and then running the command in both modes takes longer.
In summary

```
subprocess.check_output([command]) //returns immediately
subprocess.check_output([command, "-i"]) // takes longer to run, returns output
subprocess.call([command]) // also takes longer to run
```

The command is running a go program, in which in case of the non interactive mode, I disable the output. Is it possible that because of this check_output returns immediately? From the documentation I understood that it's supposed to wait for the subprocess to return.

I have checked running the command from outside of the python script and in both interactive and standard mode it takes "a bit" to run.

Comment: First check if check_output throws an exception, or does it just return?

Comment: are you sure you see stderr? Try: `print('it should be visible', file=sys.stderr)`.

Answer (score 0):

If [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) has returned; it means the child process is not  running. Moreover if [`check_output()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/81b46e4a08f071c5da3a8396d121b7463de4b830/Lib/subprocess.py#L562-L618) doesn't raise an exception then it means that the child process has returned with a zero exit status (it indicates success in many cases).

A command may change its behavior depending on whether it thinks it is run interactively in a terminal or not e.g., [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)
What exactly are the changes depends on a particular command e.g., [`apt-get` stops reporting progress when stdout is redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923901/4279).