# Threaded subprocess read is not give any output

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, stdout

I have the following code and am trying to run in in Idle in linux.

```
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading  import Thread

try:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()

p = Popen(['youtube-dl', '-l', '-c', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utV1sdjr4PY'],   stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)

q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()

# ... do other things here

# read line without blocking
while True:
    try:  line = q.get_nowait() # or q.get(timeout=.1)
    except Empty:
        pass
        #print('no output yet')
    else: # got line
        print line
```

But is is always printing "no output yet".
**Edit: I edited the code and it is working. But I have another problem. The percentage of the download is updated in a single line, but the code reads it only after the line is complete**

Comment: Because of the bikini, maybe? try sys.stdout.write("\rNo line") instead of print('no output yet'). You will see some output, but I don't know if the one you search for

Comment: @cox What does this have to do with a bikini?

Comment: Try the script(or follow the youtube link). It is „Sexy Bikini Girls Epic Fail Compilation 2013-AYlb-7TXMxM.mp4”.

Comment: @cox _facepalm_ thanks for the warning.

Comment: @cox It is working but I have another problem now. Check the edit!

Comment: It may be because of youtube-dl: when write to a single line, it use the \r and \b flags - like in may answer. But from cli, the \n is the „end of file/strem” marker, so the sys don't see the changes before the new lines inserted. I may be wrong.

Comment: Let me check with sequential read

Comment: @cox I think     for line in iter(out.readline, b''): is making it wait until a new line is spit out.

Comment: No, the std won't flush until a new line

Comment: Maybe lets try unbuffering youtube-dl woth somethink from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1544690/1219585 ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's put the comments in an answer.

```
import sys, os
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from time import sleep
import pty

master, slave = pty.openpty()
stdout = os.fdopen(master)

p = Popen(['youtube-dl', '-l', '-c', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYlb-7TXMxM'], shell=False,stdout=slave,stderr=slave, close_fds=True)

while True:
    #line = stdout.readline().rstrip() - will strip the new line
    line = stdout.readline()
    if line != b'':
        sys.stdout.write("\r%s" % line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(.1)
```

If you want a thread and a diferent while, I sugest wrapping in a class and avoid queue. The output is „unbuffered” - thanks @FilipMalckzak

Comment: P.S.: I see you've changed the link. I have no problem with robots, but things move faster with bikini.

Comment: Your script is still not printing new lines until they're finished.

Comment: It works for me. I am not at home, but I will re-test. What platform are you on?