# forcing a program to flush its standard output when redirected

Tags: c, linux, stdio, fifo

i have a closed source program that prints output to standard output. i need to parse the output. so i redirect the output to a fifo (from which i can read in the parent process that forks and execs the binary) using dup2 and then exec the program. the problem is that the fprintf calls in the file become buffered because it is now writing to a file.

i tried calling setvbuf with _IONBF on stdout before calling exec. but the problem still exists.

why does setvbuf not help in my case?

how can i force the output to get flushed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setvbuf()` makes no difference because it changes the state of part of the C runtime library, not part of the OS.  When the new process begins running, its C runtime library will be reinitialised (that's if it uses a CRT at all!)

The only way I have heard of for getting around this is to somehow fake a terminal to the process.  That's because most CRT libraries will by default perform only line buffering if they believe they are attached to an interactive terminal (in the Unix world: if `isatty()` returns true on the file descriptor), whereas otherwise they will buffer in larger blocks (typically 8Kb or so).

[This utility](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) looks like a pretty good place to start.  (Borrowed from a comment on [Trick an application into thinking its stdin is interactive, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe), which has other useful info.)

Comment: i fork out a process, call setvbuf in the child process and then exec a shell script that execs another shell script that finally execs the binary. can i change the final exec command (bash) so that it disables buffering somehow.

Comment: I repeat, it's useless to call setvbuf() before execing -- none of the C runtime library state is preserved across exec()! The final process you exec() might not even *use* the CRT! (Unlikely but possible.)

Comment: ok i am trying the pty approach
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056858/cannot-write-to-pty-linux

Answer (score 4):

The `unbuffer` tool can assist with this issue:

It's part of the `expect-dev` and can be installed in ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install expect-dev
```

to use it type:

```
unbuffer ls > log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have something like this in your program (you can reproduce this for your tests, I'm calling it `isatty` here)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char* m1 = "%d: %s a TTY\n";

void isTty(FILE* f) {
    int fno = fileno(f);
    printf(m1, fno, (isatty(fno)) ? "is" : "is NOT");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    isTty(stdin);
    isTty(stdout);
}
```

for example if you run it

```
$ ./isatty
0: is a TTY
1: is a TTY

$ ./isatty > isatty.out
$ cat isatty.out 
0: is a TTY
1: is NOT a TTY

$ ./isatty > isatty.out < /dev/null
$ cat isatty.out 
0: is NOT a TTY
1: is NOT a TTY
```

Now if you create an `expect` script `isatty.expect` (install `expect` for your distro if not installed)

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

spawn "./isatty"
expect
```

and run it

```
$ ./isatty.expect 
spawn ./isatty
0: is a TTY
1: is a TTY
```

or

```
$ ./isatty.expect > isatty.out 
$ cat isatty.out 
spawn ./isatty
0: is a TTY
1: is a TTY
```