# cannot write to pty - linux

Tags: java, c, linux, bash, terminal

i am the owner of the pty device created like this
permissions are crw-w----

```
mknod pty1 c 1 1
cat > pty1
```

tells me operation not permitted.

what i want to do later is that i open the file from a program using open and call write to send output to the terminal, as if it is a disk file.

why is cat not working.
can we **write to a pty** or **read from a pty** using open and write.

can we do this from java. java writes to a file that is actually a pty.

source of problem:
[forcing a program to flush its standard output when redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055918/forcing-a-program-to-flush-its-standard-output-when-redirected/)

**Update**: is the question not clear. do i need to add more info?

output of ls -la

```
crw--w---- 1 iamrohitbanga users 1, 1 2010-01-13 18:27 pty1
crw--w---- 1 iamrohitbanga users 1, 2 2010-01-13 18:29 pty2
```

also

when i do
cat /dev/pts/0 in one terminal and cat > /dev/pts/0 in another, i do not see the input of one getting transferred to another.

Comment: Did you see this answer?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe/1401557#1401557

Comment: i want to write to a pty in a transparent manner, as if it were a file on the file system. that is why i was testing using cat. is it not possible.

Comment: Please show full output from ls -l, which user and group owns the device file? Also is there anything interesting in dmesg?

Comment: why was i voted down. if you think my question is invalid, let me know the reason.

Comment: +1 because I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how PTYs work; you should read [`man 4 pty`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pty&sektion=4) and [`man 4 pts`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pts&sektion=4).  (The old BSD-style devices should no longer be used.)

In order to open a pseudo-terminal slave (PTS, the `/dev/pts/#` returned by [`ptsname(3)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ptsname&sektion=3)), another program must create a pseudo-terminal master (PTM, returned by [`posix_openpt(3)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=posix_openpt&sektion=3)) and enable the PTS with [`grantpt(3)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grantpt&sektion=3) and [`unlockpt(3)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=unlockpt&sektion=3).

Using the [`forkpty(3)` etc.](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=openpty&sektion=3) helper functions is a lot easier than calling the low-level functions yourself.

And even after that, it doesn't work like a FIFO (which you seem to be expecting): anything written into the PTS comes out on the PTM, and anything read from the PTS is written from the PTM.