# Ruby IO.popen STDOUT buffering

Tags: ruby, popen

I'm working on a script that uses IO.popen to open another program and continually read the data. It's like this:

```
process = IO.popen(["/the/program", "argument", "argument"])

loop do
  line = process.gets
  puts "#{line}"
end
```

(The actual program does more than just printing the output, obviously - that's just an example.)

The issue I'm running into is that popen seems to be buffering STDOUT from the opened process. I've confirmed this by running the program directly from a shell and through popen, side-by-side, and the Ruby one never gets one line at a time. It always gets multiple lines at a time, and is delayed.

I've tried

```
STDOUT.sync = true
```

... before popen, but that hasn't changed anything.

The program in question is definitely using \n as a new line, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you try `process.sync = true`?

Comment: @Eddie did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have the source to the other program?  You either need to force the other program to flush its output, or make your script look like a pty (see the `pty` standard lib).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055918/forcing-a-program-to-flush-its-standard-output-when-redirected) for a good explanation of what's going on.

**EDIT**: pty sample code:

```
require 'pty'
PTY.spawn "some-command" do |r,w,p|
  loop { puts r.gets }
end
```

Comment: This fails to print the last line if it doesn't end in a newline (e.g. if some-command is echo -n ABC).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `/the/program` is buffering when it detects stdout is not a terminal - you can test by piping through cat, eg:

```
"/the/program" "argument" "argument" | cat
```

The answer above, will solve it if that is the problem, ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pty'
PTY.spawn "./the-program testing one Two three" do |r,w,p|
  loop { puts "GOT: #{r.gets}" }  
end
```

Some languages (eg C) detect if stdout is a terminal and change to line buffered - see [Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default/3746795#3746795)

As an example when it works, I used a simple bash script to output each argument and the time, one at a time, with 3 seconds in between between and the ruby script worked without a problem. I added eof detection for this example.

Modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

process = IO.popen(["./the-program", "testing", "one", "Two", "three"])

while !process.eof?
  line = process.gets
  puts "GOT: #{line}"
end
```

the-program contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg
do
  echo $arg
  date
  sleep 3
done
```

I tried with ruby version 1.9.3 and 2.1.2

```
$ ruby ,p
GOT: testing
GOT: Mon Jun 16 06:19:00 EST 2014
GOT: one
GOT: Mon Jun 16 06:19:03 EST 2014
GOT: Two
GOT: Mon Jun 16 06:19:06 EST 2014
GOT: three
GOT: Mon Jun 16 06:19:09 EST 2014
$
```

If I use a C program instead, then the problem reoccurs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
                sleep(3);
        }
}
```