# Redirect IO for child process

Tags: c, linux, stdio, io-redirection

I wrote a program that redirects IO of a child process. The problem I'm having is that the new stdout and stderr aren't writing straight to file, they're buffering in memory instead. I tried to fix this, with setvbuf, but have had no luck.

I'm getting no errors with the return of the function.

This is pretty frustrating because I had removed buffering in a previous implementation, but I lost the files somehow. In any case, I'm not sure why setvbuf isn't fixing my issue.

```
if (!freopen(DBGD_CHILD_STDOUT, "w", stdout)){
    perror ("Couldn't open new child-stdout");
    exit (-1);
}

if (!freopen(DBGD_CHILD_STDERR, "w", stderr)){
    perror ("Couldn't open new parent-stderr");
    exit (-1);
}

if (setvbuf (stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)){
    perror ("Couldn't change buffering mode of stdout");
    exit (-1);
}

if (setvbuf (stderr, 0, _IONBF, 0)){
    perror ("Couldn't change buffering mode of stderr");
    exit (-1);
}

if (execv (ProcessArgs[0], &ProcessArgs[1]) < 0){
    perror ("Couldn't execute process");
    exit (-1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055918/forcing-a-program-to-flush-its-standard-output-when-redirected

Comment: thanks. I'll show an implementation without setvbuf, that I had tried previously.

Comment: @Michael actually, I may try using a pseudo terminal - as that question has brought up. Let me look more into it

Comment: can you post all your code?

Comment: I can tomorrow morning. Basically from the entry point: there is a fork(), chdir(), and a call to pipe() and dup2() (for stdin) and then the code above. I can give more feedback when I wake up tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what really happens from your description and the small code chunk.

However, the attempts to change buffering before `execv` will have no effect, as the process will be replaced as a whole, including libc stdio state. You need to change buffering in the executed child process instead.

If you don't control the child, then you can execute it with [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html).

Comment: I can't change it from the child process, that's not part of the design I want

Comment: thanks, that worked. I'm probably going to use a pseudo terminal