# Disable Standard I/O buffering when redirecting child I/O using CreateProcess()

Tags: c, redirect, winapi, process, pipe

In Windows, you can create a child process with redirected I/O using anonymous pipes, as described here: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)

But, when Stdout is redirected to a non-interactive device like a pipe, it's automatically set to buffered mode. This creates a devastatingly tangled I/O situation. That is, I don't get Stdout's data, until it's manually flushed, or the program terminates. I think, the only elegant solution to this problem is to disable standard I/O buffering at the creation of the child process.[CreateProcess()]

The question is how can I do it? Any example with codes will be very appreciated. (Note: I've searched the Internet, but I can't even get close to the solution.) Thanks!

EDIT: The actual question is, in win32 API how can I disable standard I/O buffering of a child process before creating it using CreateProcess() ?

EDIT-2: I guess I found a pretty hack for this problem. Stdout only full-buffers when *file descriptor* is not a 'TTY'(Terminal/Console device), if I can somehow make my Pipe a Pseudo-TTY then the problem would be fixed. So, the question is How can I make/set a pipe as a pseudo-TTY in windows? I cannot find any solution in the Internet.

Comment: buffered I/O is not "devastatingly tangled", and you can get stdout data without waiting for a "manual" flush or program termination.  As soon as the producer fills the buffer, reads in the reader will complete.

Comment: it depends on how the particular program is written. and this can not be controlled. but i at all never view any standard windows console app (like cmd) which have such problem

Comment: @RbMm, it's a problem with long-running processes that write output intermittently if they use the default full buffering (4 KiB) when writing to a non-character device such as a pipe. In Linux there are workarounds such as using `LD_PRELOAD` via `stdbuf` or a pty via `unbuffer`. In Windows you can use the console to try to emulate a pty, but polling the screen buffer isn't reliable like reading from a pipe. I also saw a suggestion to hook `GetFileType` in the child.

Comment: @eryksun - this, how i say, depend from child implementation - which functions is used for write to stdout

Comment: @RbMm, a considerate application should have a command-line option to control the buffering of its output, but in the real world most programs that use C stdio don't even think about this. We're stuck with hacky workarounds such as `stdbuf` or `unbuffer`.

Comment: C/C++ libraries typically buffer STDOUT data in memory before flushing it to the actual console, so there is nothing the launching process can do to change that behavior.

Comment: *in win32 API how can I disable standard I/O buffering* - you can not do this.  I/O buffering mean that application write data to memory buffer instead write to file (pipe). so this is absolute unrelated to win api at all. you can not control this behaviour

Comment: To address the problem practically (we can't rebuild all applications that just use the CRT defaults) and reliably, Windows needs a built-in pty system -- for which the ConDrv device driver could probably be extended. For now you could try a hacky solution with [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty), which I've seen mentioned a few times recently, e.g. see the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46443665/205580).