# Fool a windows program into believing it's running with output unredirected

Tags: windows, flush, output-redirect

Is it possible to fool a windows program (using a python script or any other shell to launch it) into believing that its output isn't redirected, so the output is not buffered ?

(Well, that's a simular question as [forcing a program to flush its standard output when redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055918/forcing-a-program-to-flush-its-standard-output-when-redirected) except that it's windows specific, the question only tackles linux)

Comment: isatty() is a very low-level call.  Patching the GetFileType winapi function with another program is only theoretically possible.

Comment: @HansPassant, do you mean to hook `GetFileType` to check if it's querying a standard handle, and in that case always return `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`?

Comment: I think I found some `unbuffer` program equivalent for windows, I have to test it (needs MSYS2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516258/what-is-the-equivalent-of-unbuffer-program-on-windows

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that's interesting, but it's not actually fooling the program, unlike Linux stdbuf. It's really using a console. I've used console screen buffers with child processes before, but only in the simple case when I can use a large screen with 9,999 lines and not have to worry about scrolling. The screen buffer isn't like a pipe that blocks when full, so winpty has to poll it. I wonder how reliable that is. Other programs such as ConEmu use DLL injection to hook `WriteFile` and `WriteConsole` in the target process.

Comment: I'd suggest trying `com0com` or similar, should work without having to scrape screen buffers *or* injecting into the target process.  I haven't actually tried it though.