# Fake output stream type

Tags: stream

By default certain programs format their output according to the type of the stream they write to. For example, the output of `ls` and `ls > file` looks differently. I'd like to know how this is achieved by a program. Additionally, is there a way by which we can trick such programs as if the output stream is a terminal where it actually is a file (especially when they don't have any options that affect output formatting)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via `isatty`:

```
if (!isatty(fileno(stdout))
{
    // redirected to a file or piped to a process
}
```

One way to trick is instead of doing redirect, start `script`.  Now everything that goes to the 'tty' (including what you type into stdin and what is sent to output) is sent to a file called typescript.

Comment: Better check stdout, not stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Those programs use `isatty(fileno(stdout))` to check if they are writing to a TTY (terminal) or something else (e.g. a pipe).

About faking a tty, check [Trick an application into thinking its stdin is interactive, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe)