# interacting with the terminal in linux for passwords?

Tags: linux, terminal

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247517/redirect-stdin-in-bash) and doing echo pass | cmd and cmd <<< pass do not work with mysql and another app i tried.

One guy comments that passwords are through the terminal and not stdin, that sounds secure. How do i do that? using bash, .NET or C++?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following can help...

```
expect -c 'spawn mysql -uroot -p; expect assword; send "toor\n"; interact'
```

...though I'm not sure I understood correctly your question.