# redirecting the output of shell command to &- what does it mean

Tags: shell, redirect, scripting, output

I am new to shell scripting and having a doubt regarding the usage of &-

I have a shell script with a single line: `echo Hello`.
The shell script is named `demo.sh`

What does it do when it is executed as:

```
./demo.sh 0>&-
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It closes the file descriptor - standard input (0) in this case.

See also:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html