# bash: force exec'd process to have unbuffered stdout

Tags: bash, logging, exec, unbuffered-output

I've got a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/some_binary > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
```

Problem is that `some_binary` sends all of its logging to stdout, and buffering makes it so that I only see output in chunks of a few lines. This is annoying when something gets stuck and I need to see what the last line says.

Is there any way to make stdout unbuffered before I do the exec that will affect some_binary so it has more useful logging?

(The wrapper script is only setting a few environment variables before the exec, so a solution in perl or python would also be feasible.)

Comment: Dennis's answer is *exactly* right. Here's why. Programs on Unix that use C stdio for output will buffer when the output is not going to a terminal (boosts performance a lot) unless told not to with `setvbuf`; hardly anyone bothers with that. The `expect` system (of which `unbuffer` is a trivial application) uses black magic with Unix pseudo-terminal devices (ptys) to run programs with a terminal that isn't a real terminal so that the wrapped program doesn't buffer its output. It's clever, but be warned: most systems only have a limited number of ptys; a naturally unbuffered program is better.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work so well on Windows. That's because expect on that platform uses debugging magic instead of terminal magic (because this is an area where Windows is *very* different).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to opt for modifying `some_binary` to do the right thing instead of relying on the black magic. `expect` is great, but I don't want it here...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might find that the `unbuffer` script that comes with [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) may help.

Comment: Does not work with the `echo -n .` or `prinff "."` which I need in my case to show a progressbar in bash

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe

Answer (score 37):

GNU coreutils-8.5 also has the [`stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) command to modify I/O stream buffering:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

So, in your example case, simply invoke:

```
stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/some_binary > /tmp/my.log 2>&1
```

This will allow text to appear immediately line-by-line (once a line is completed with the end-of-line `"\n"` character in C). If you really want immediate output, use `-o0` instead.

This way could be more desirable if you do not want to introduce dependency to [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) via `unbuffer` command. The `unbuffer` way, on the other hand, is needed if you have to fool `some_binary` into thinking that it is facing a real tty standard output.

Answer (score 11):

Some command line programs have an option to modify their stdout stream buffering behaviour. So that's the way to go if the C source is available ...

```
# two command options ...
man file | less -p '--no-buffer'
man grep | less -p '--line-buffered'

# ... and their respective source code

# from: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-6.2.1/file/src/file.c
if(nobuffer)
   (void) fflush(stdout);

# from: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/grep/grep-28/grep/src/grep.c
if (line_buffered)
   fflush (stdout);
```

As an alternative to using expect's unbuffer script or modifying the program's source code, you may also try to use script(1) to avoid stdout hiccups caused by a pipe:

See: [Trick an application into thinking its stdin is interactive, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe)

```
# Linux
script -c "[executable string]" /dev/null

# FreeBSD, Mac OS X
script -q /dev/null "[executable string]"
```

Comment: On Mac OS X, because "script" may change return code from "\n" to "\r\n", I needed to run like this: `script -q /dev/null commands... | perl -pe 's/\n/\r\n/g'`

Answer (score 3):

I scoured the internets for an answer, and none of this worked for `uniq` which is too stubborn to buffer everything except for `stdbuf`:

`{piped_command_here} | stdbuf -oL uniq | {more_piped_command_here}`

Answer (score 2):

GNU Coreutils-8 includes a program called stdbuf which essentially does the LD_PRELOAD trick. It works on Linux and reportedly works on BSD systems.

Answer (score 2):

An environment variable can set the terminal IO mode to unbuffered.

export NSUnbufferedIO=YES

This will set the terminal unbuffered for both C and Ojective-C terminal output commands.