# incremental output with subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am using `subprocess` module for running commands from another app I know that you are able to do the following

```
import subprocess

app = subprocess(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = app.communicate()
print out
```

I would like the output to be displayed as it happening as supposed to one big blob at the end. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may be that the command you are running in the subprocess buffers its output: in which case, in Blender's answer, the `process.stdout.read(1)` would not return until the output buffer of the subprocess filled up, causing it to be flushed, and thus seen by the parent process.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234687/pyside-qprocess-need-help) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout) for more information about how buffering affects things.

Here's some scripts to illustrate:

```
# spew.py
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    print 'Message no. %d' % i
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and

```
# runspew.py
import subprocess
import time

start = time.time()
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'spew.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = p.stdout.read(1)
print 'Elapsed time to first byte read: %.2f' % (time.time() - start)
data = p.stdout.read()
print 'Elapsed time to last byte read: %.2f' % (time.time() - start)
p.wait()
```

Now, put both scripts in the same directory and run `python runspew.py`. You'll see something like this:

```
Elapsed time to first byte read: 10.05
Elapsed time to last byte read: 10.05
```

Now, remove the comment from `sys.stdout.flush()` in `spew.py` and do `python runspew.py` again. You'll now see something like this:

```
Elapsed time to first byte read: 0.02
Elapsed time to last byte read: 10.04
```

Notice that `runspew.py` didn't change: only the program which was run as the subprocess did. If the program you're running can't be made to run unbuffered (or flush frequently), then you'll have to use `expect`/`unbuffer` as described in the other answers I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

I made a Python shell implementation once, so here's the code I used to run commands. It ran `wget` and `nano` fine, so I think the code would suit your needs:

```
  process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

  while True:
    output = process.stdout.read(1)

    if output == '' and process.poll() != None:
      break

    if output != '':
      sys.stdout.write(output)
      sys.stdout.flush()
```

Basically, you have to write directly into `stdout`.

Comment: what is the complete variable for?

Comment: The key really is to call `sys.stdout.flush()`, otherwise Python will continue buffering output.

Comment: @dustyprogrammer, I don't actually know XD. I checked my code, and this is the only time it's even used. Time to cut off a vestigial organ...