# Redirect stdout to fifo immediately

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, fifo

I have, for example, a c program that prints three lines, two seconds apart, that is:

```
  printf("Wait 2 seconds...\n");
  sleep(2);
  printf("Two more\n");
  sleep(2);
  printf("Quitting in 2 seconds...\n");
  sleep(2);
```

I execute the program and redirect it to a pipe:

```
./printer > myPipe
```

On another terminal

```
cat < myPipe
```

The second terminal prints all at once, 6 seconds later! I would like it to print the available lines immediatly. How can i do it?

**Obs:** I can't change the source code. It's actually the output of a boardgame algorithm, i have to get it immediatly so that i can plug it into another algorithm, get the answer back and plug into the first one...

Comment: Use `tail -f myPipe` instead of `cat < myPipe` and don't forget to call `fflush` in your *C* program

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the program to this approach:

```
  printf("Wait 2 seconds...\n");
  fflush (stdout);
  sleep(2);
  printf("Two more\n");
  fflush (stdout);
  sleep(2);
  printf("Quitting in 2 seconds...\n");
  fflush (stdout);
  sleep(2);
```

---

Additional:

If you can't change the program, there really is no way to affect the program's built-in buffering without hacking it.

If you can relink the program, you could substitute a `printf()` function which flushes after each call.  Or changes the startup initialization of stdout to be unbuffered—or at least line buffered.

Comment: @anishsane, No, that's my problem. That's only if stdout is on a terminal. In my case, in which it's been redirected to a pipe, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the source, you might want to try some of the solutions to this related question:
[bash: force exec'd process to have unbuffered stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout)

Basically, you have to make the OS execute this program interactively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the actual source file is complete. If so, then you have to compile the source and run it to get it to do anything. Using `cat` will just print the contents of the file, **not** run it.

If it was written in bash  then it would have to be set mode bit +x, which would then make it executable. Allowing you to run it from a terminal ./script

No need to worry about the syntax since you've stated it's not an option to change it and... It's correctly written in C.