# Force a program created using `exec` to perform unbuffered I/O

Tags: c, io, exec, fork, pipe

I am trying to interact with an external program in C using `pipe`, `fork` and `exec`. I want to force the external program to perform unbuffered I/O. Here's a relevant snippet from my code so far:

```
...
pid = fork();
if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
{
    /* child process */

    /* make pipe connections to standard streams */             
    dup2(wpipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(rpipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* close pipe endings */
    close(wpipe[0]); close(rpipe[0]);
    close(wpipe[1]); close(rpipe[1]);

    /* unbuffered I/O */
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ); 

    if (execl("path/to/some_binary", "path/to/some_binary", (char *) NULL) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "exec failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
...
```

This does not work because streams do not survive across `exec` calls. So using `setvbuf` to force unbuffered I/O does not work, because the program image (`some_binary`) creates stdin and stdout streams of its own, and does not use the streams that I called `setvbuf` on.

The program does work when I re-build `some_binary` after adding the `setvbuf` calls in its code. But how can this be done if you do not have any control over the binary you are passing to `exec`? How can this be made to work for, say, a unix command like `cat` or `ls`?

Comment: Check the `unbuffer` command that comes with [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Why do you ask?? What is the use-case????

Comment: When doing two-way communication with a sub-process using two pipes. With I/O buffering, read operations in the parent process get blocked simply because the output has been buffered by the child sub-process.

Comment: What *exactly* is the program running (after `execve`) in the *child* process?

Comment: related: [There are existing utilities that can do it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/4279). Ignore Python-specific code or reimplement it in C e.g., there is a select loop over pseudo-tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want in the general case (unbuffering after [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) of arbitrary executables...)

Buffering is done by code (e.g. by some `libc` code related to `<stdio.h>`). And the code is defined by the program being `execve`-ed.

You might perhaps play with [LD_PRELOAD tricks](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) which might call `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);` *after* the `execve` (but before the `main`....); but this would work only with dynamically linked executables.

Perhaps using some `constructor` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in some initialization function of your `LD_PRELOAD`-ed shared object might *sometimes* do the trick. Or redefine `printf`, `fopen`, .... in that shared object...

#### addenda

You commented that you do :

> two-way communication with a sub-process using two pipes.

Then your approach is wrong. The parent process should monitor the two pipes, probably with a multiplexing call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), then (according to the result of that multiplexing) decide to read or to write to the child process. In reality, you want some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop): either implement a simple **event *loop*** yourself (with e.g. `poll` [iteratively called many times] inside a repeated *loop*) or use some existing one (see [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), or the one provided by some toolkit like [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/qt5) etc...)

<sup>You might also multiplex with [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) but I recommend `poll` because of the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)</sup>

You won't lose your time by reading [Advanced Linux Programming](https://archive.org/details/ost-computer-science-advanced-linux-programming/mode/2up).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/) to your next related question.

Comment: Thank you for the addendum! Is the poll function available in GNU C? Why does it not appear in the documentation of GNU C?

Comment: What do you call GNU C? Is it [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) the compiler (which is unrelated to your question) or [Glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (a.k.a. GNU libc) the standard C library? `poll` is documented in POSIX [poll](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) and in the man pages!! And GNU libc does not document all of POSIX (but assumes it is known). BTW, GNU libc documents [select](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html#Waiting-for-I_002fO) -which is an old-fashion way to multiplex.

Comment: I meant glibc. I couldn't find the poll function documented on this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html

Comment: I tried to implement polling, but again ran into problems because of buffering - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581466/using-poll-function-with-buffered-streams

Comment: You need an *event loop* the `poll` should be *repeated* inside a loop... (with *different* actions when you get *readable* and *writable* file descriptors given by `poll`)

Answer (score 0):

You **can** actually do that!

One way to do that is to just replace your pipe/socketpair with openpty():

```
int master, slave, pid;

if (openpty(&master, &slave, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("openpty");
    return -1;
}

pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    return -1;
}

if (pid == 0) {
    setsid();
    if (ioctl(slave, TIOCSCTTY, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("ioctl slave TIOCSCTTY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(slave, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(slave, STDERR_FILENO);

    execvp(args[0], args);
    perror("execvp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Sample read/write using select, add a flow control by yourself

struct timeval tv;

fd_set fdr, fdw;
FD_ZERO(&fdr);
FD_SET(master, &fdr);
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
if (select(master+1, &fdr, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) {
    printf("Nothing to read\n");
}
if (FD_ISSET(master, &fdr)) {
    // Read stuff...
}

FD_ZERO(&fdw);
FD_SET(master, &fdw);
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
if (select(master+1, NULL, &fdw, NULL, &tv) < 0) {
    printf("Not ready to write\n");
}
if (FD_ISSET(master, &fdw)) {
    // Write stuff...
}
```

Or alternatively you may use `stdbuf` in your exec() path to start your program, see
[bash: force exec'd process to have unbuffered stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout)

Both methods worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You might try to pause the task, then modify its image. You can do it via gdb or the /proc filesystem.
In particular, you have the access to all fds the task created via the /proc filesystem.

UPDATE:

If the buffering is done by glibc, just override the relevant function in glibc, by defining your own function, compiling it into a shared library and loading with the program.