# How to check the timer task is running in the background?

Tags: c, linux, timer, alarm, rtos

The code below is for receiving a data from the master via the socket for udp layer. There are some API supported in my project and I created a timer task for calling the task for every 2ms, 10ms and so on.

I am debugging this program on the embedded PC target in eclipse IDE using remote C/C++ application. I am calling the `maketimer (alarm)` inside the `CreateSocket` function. But how to check the timer task calling the function TASK1, TASK2 and TASK3 for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms in the background?

```
#include "MAIN.h"

#define BILLION  1000000L

timer_t firstTimerID, secondTimerID, thirdTimerID;
double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;

int connectedSocket, acceptSocket;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
struct sockaddr client, dest;
char buf[128];
long rc, sentbytes;
int port = 18017;


void TASK1(Task2ms_Raster)
{

    struct timespec start, stop;
    uint32 StartTime, StopTime;

    if( (StartTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror("clock gettime");

    }

    // return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 2ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_2msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload2ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 2ms. */
    counter32 += slope32;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 2ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass2ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_2msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto2ms;
        }
    }
    if( (StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
    }

    duration2ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
        + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
        / (double)BILLION;
    printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration2ms );
}

void TASK2(Task10ms_Raster)
{
    struct timespec start, stop;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
    }

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_10msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload10ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 10ms. */
    counter16 += slope16;

    /* Trigger STIM for the 10ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass10ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_10msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto10ms;
        }
    }

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
    }
    XCP_FN_TYPE Xcp_CmdProcessor ( );

    duration10ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
        + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
        / (double)BILLION;
    printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration10ms );
}


void TASK3(Task100ms_Raster)
{
    struct timespec start, stop;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror( "clock gettime" );

    }

    /* Trigger DAQ for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_100msRstr( ))
    {
        ++numDaqOverload100ms;
    }

    /* Update those variables which are modified every 100ms. */
    counter8 += slope8;


    /* Trigger STIM for the 100ms XCP raster. */
    if( enableBypass100ms )
    {
        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_100msRstr( ) )
        {
            ++numMissingDto100ms;
        }
    }

    if((clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 ) 
    {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
    }

    duration100ms = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
        + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
        / (double)BILLION;
    printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration100ms );
}

static void timerHandler( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc )
{
    timer_t *tidp;

    tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

    if ( *tidp == firstTimerID )

        TASK1(Task2ms_Raster);
    else if ( *tidp == secondTimerID )
        TASK2(Task10ms_Raster);
    else if ( *tidp == thirdTimerID )
        TASK3(Task100ms_Raster);
}

static int makeTimer( char *name, timer_t *timerID, int expireMS, int intervalMS )
{
    struct sigevent         te;
    struct itimerspec       its;
    struct sigaction        sa;
    int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

    /* Set up signal handler. */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
    }

    /* Set and enable alarm */
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
    timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

    return 1;
}

int CreateSocket()
{
    if(rc!=0)
    {
        printf("socket failure code: %ld\n",rc);

        return 1;
    }

    else

    {
        printf("socket started!\n");
    }

    // Socket creation for UDP

    acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    if(acceptSocket==-1)
    {
        printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket started!\n");
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

    if(rc== -1)
    {

        printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
    }


    while(rc!=-1)
    {
        rc= recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf,128,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        if(rc==0)
        {
            printf("Server has no connection..\n");
            break;
        }
        if(rc==-1)
        {
            printf("failure: recv, failure code\n");
            break;
        }
        XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );

        makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
        makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
        makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms

        //    buf[rc]='\0';
        //    printf("Client sendet: %s\n",buf);
        //    sprintf(buf2,"Du mich auch %s",buf);
        //    rc=sendto(connectedSocket,buf2,strlen(buf2),0);
    }

    close(acceptSocket);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Xcp_Initialize();
    CreateSocket();
    return 0;
}

void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{
    if ((long)XcpPort==port)
    {
        sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest));
    }
    XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [time(7)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

BTW, your `BILLION` is wrong. You probably should have

```
#define BILLION 1.0e9
```

<sup>(since you are using it only in floating point expressions)</sup>

You could have three threads (read a [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)), one for TASK1, one for TASK2, one for TASK3 (perhaps using [clock_nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html)...). Or (preferably) you could have a single [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (around e.g. a [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or `ppoll(2)` multiplexing call....), perhaps also using [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) to get timer events, and also managing the sockets.
See [this example of `poll`-based event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108). You should adapt it to also use a file descriptor obtained with `timerfd_create`.. You could also use some event looping library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/)

Notice that 2 milliseconds is a very small delay. (How reliable do you want that to be?)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: I am using hpet in my program for calling the task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. Why cant I use one thread and call the  makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
            makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
            makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms   ??

Comment: I am using alarm and handler to call the task for 2ms,10 and 100ms. Then also Is it necessary to use threads ??

Comment: I would use an event loop and `timerfd_create`

Comment: please could you explain more about that ?

Comment: It would take me too much time. Please read all the links I have to you.

Comment: I am using timer_create instead of timerfd_create. Will it make a difference ??

Comment: how can i use event loop w.r.t above program ?? could you give me an small example ?