# C: write() behaviors weirdly when dealing with multiple pipes

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, fork

So I have a recursive function that is going to create multiple processes and write  an integer from parent process to child process.

Everything works great when numbers are small like several hundreds/thousands.

But when numbers are large the code would always be stuck before the `write` statement. I have included an error checking for the statement but no perror was printed.

Does anyone know what's the possible cause for this?

Comment: Don't create more than a few dozens of simultaneous child processes. `fork`-ing a thousand of them is almost certainly wrong. Also, check *every* syscall (including `fork` and `pipe` and `write` and `read` ...). At last, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use a debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is a homework and the algorithm provided asks us to do it this way ..

Answer (score 0):

When you [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) the writing can be blocked if the process on the other end of the pipe did not read from it (and the pipe is full).

You could use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) in your [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

But you should avoid creating more than a few dozens of simultaneous child processes. See also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NPROC` (and the bash `ulimit` builtin).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: hmm what should I do then?

Comment: I don't think we have learned in class. Then it must be something wrong with my own algorithm.. thanks anyway!

Comment: No, add an event loop into your code. Your teacher is expecting you to learn.