# Stopping blocking write to fifo after reading ends

Tags: c, linux, debian, fifo

When reading process quits, how do i determine it from writing process before write call blocks ? Normally when read side closes, write call on the write side should return an error right?

client

```
while(!timeout)
{
    read(fd, message, BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

server

```
while(1)
{
    length = write(fd, message, strlen(message));
    if(length <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write a short program and try it to see what behavior happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> When a process tries to write to a FIFO that is not opened for read
>          on the other side, the process is sent a SIGPIPE signal.

You could -and probably should- use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to test dynamic readability or writability of a fifo or pipe or socket file descriptor (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108) about a simplistic [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using `poll`). See also [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) & [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: I am very surprised by the number of times people are asking here what the `man` pages give immediately and quickly. They have forgotten what [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) means - and also STFW. I'm old enough to have learn Unix by reading the man pages on paper (at SunOS3.2 time, probably 1987).

Comment: My problem is after writing / reading some data between processes when reading program ends writing one still tries to write and blocking.

Comment: Use `poll` before attempting the `write`; very probably you need to build your programs around an *event loop*.