# how to save the output of GCC in a file using pipes in C (linux)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

on execution, file creation is working well...but nothing gets written into it...what could be done...is there any other way apart from using file descriptors..??

I tried the following code:

```
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    read_fp = popen("gcc test1.c", "r");
    //fp = fopen("/home/pranav/Desktop/b4.txt","w");
    fd = open("beejoutput2.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP  |         S_IROTH);
    if (read_fp != NULL)
    {

        chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ, read_fp);
        while (chars_read > 0)
        {

    /*writing to the file*/
        while ((bytesread = read(3, buffer, chars_read)) > 0) 
                write(fd, buffer, bytesread);

        buffer[chars_read-1] = '\0';
        printf("Reading %d:-\n %s\n", BUFSIZ, buffer);
        //fprintf(fp,"%d:-\n %s\n", BUFSIZ, buffer);
        chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ, read_fp);
        }



    pclose(read_fp);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    //fclose(fp);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: First, your output might be on stderr rather than stdout.  Next, your code is a bit of a puzzle.  You appear to do an initial (huge) fread but then discard that output.  Then you inexplicable read from hard coded file descriptor 3???  And then you fread some more, again discarding the result...

Comment: Why the `(bytesread = read(3, buffer, chars_read)`, why do you hardcode the file descriptor 3?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) since your code is very confused! You may want to code an event loop, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108) ....

Answer (score 1):

Error messages will be on stderr, so change this

> read_fp = popen("gcc test1.c", "r");

to this

> read_fp = popen("gcc test1.c 2>&1", "r");

Answer (score 1):

1. You should test the output of *open* and *write* since they fail.
2. You should not use system calls like *open* and *write* directly, they have portable C wrappers like *fopen* and *fwrite*.
3. Close all the things at the end.