# How to be sure that write(2) has written all the data to the socket/file-descriptor?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using `write` (man 2 write) to write data to a socket which has an established, blocking and very slow TCP-connection. I'm writing large chunks of data. `write` returns the actual size written and of course it happens that not all data is written due to reason which are (maybe) out-of-scope of this question.

To be sure I'm encapsulating my write-call in a small loop like this:

```
do {
    ssize_t ret = write(client, p, count);
    if (ret <= 0)
        break;
    p += ret;
    count -= ret;
} while (count);

if (count != 0) 
    return -ENODEV;
```

Is there a better way to do so, like setting a flag on the file-descriptor and thus having lower-layers handle it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27623860/1606345

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24260280/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t done;
ssize_t ret;

for (done = 0; done < size; done += ret) {
    ret = write(client, buff + done, size-done);

    if (ret == 0) return -ENODEV;
    if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) { ret = 0; continue; }
    if (ret == -1)  return -errno;
}
```

Comment: Not my down vote!  Your answer is more compact and does not modify `p` nor `size`.  I'll edit mine accordingly.

Comment: I don't complain about downvotes, don't understand it either. I do think that maintaining two variables in a loop, when only one is needed, is *in general* a bad habit.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using a `while` loop instead of a `do {} while` to have consistent behaviour for the case `count == 0`.  Furthermore, some cases of failure are not errors:

```
while (count > 0) {
    ssize_t ret = write(client, p, count);
    if (ret <= 0) {
        if (ret == 0)
            return -ENODEV;
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        else
            return -errno;
    }    
    p += ret;
    count -= ret;
}
```

`EINTR` is set if the system call was interrupted by a `signal` before any data was written.  The `write` should be restarted in the case.  If the `client` handle was set to non blocking, you should also deal with `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK`.

A more compact and elegant version derived from wildplasser's answer:

```
for (size_t done = 0; done < count; ) {
    ssize_t ret = write(client, p + done, count - done);

    if (ret == 0) return -ENODEV;
    if (ret < 0 && errno != EINTR) return -errno;
    done += ret;
}
```

Comment: The `ret` varaible has loop scope. I had to hoist it out of the loop.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Too bad I cant declare it at loop scope because of the infamous `ssize_t` kludge. Hoisting out of the loop sucks, but so does moving the increment down to the end of the `for` body. I shall relunctantly choose the latter.

Comment: So finally, you end up with my solution (except fot the crippled for() loop) and +5 instead of -1 credits) I rest my case. So it goes ...