# Communicating via pipes in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent-child

I am trying to write this little program, where the parent and the child communicate with each other via pipes, the code here works, unless you 'uncomment' the commented lines, than it comes to some sort of deadlock, and I cannot figure it out why? Any ideas?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int fd[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t pid;
  pipe(fd);
  pipe(fd2);
  pid = fork();

  if(pid==0){
      close(fd[1]);
      dup2(fd[0],fileno(stdin));
      close(fd2[0]);
      FILE *output = fdopen(fd2[1],"w");
      char buffer[255];
      while(fgets(buffer,255,stdin)!=NULL)
          printf("child: %s",buffer);
  //  fprintf(output,"%s",buffer);
  } else {
      close(fd[0]);
      close(fd2[1]);
      FILE *output = fdopen(fd[1],"w");
      char buffer[255];
      while(fgets(buffer,255,stdin)!=NULL)
          fprintf(output,"%s",buffer);
      //FILE *input = fdopen(fd2[0],"r");
      //while(fgets(buffer,255,input)!=NULL)
      //  printf("Parent: %s",buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which process do you think should terminate first, the parent or the child?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the child. But also if I wait for the child process, then it is a deadlock again.

Comment: How can the child terminate? Its `while` loop waits for its `stdin` to close. Where does the parent close it? Where is the `close(fd[1])` in the parent?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it terminates when it reaches EOF (ctrl + D), then it outputs what it has read

Comment: There is no EOF. The parent never does `close(fd[1])` which would indicate end of file. If you want to send an EOF to the child, the parent needs to close its end of the pipe.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes but I do that manually, via terminal

Comment: You do *what* manually? You close the parent's side of the pipe to the child? How the heck could you do that?!

Comment: Standard C11 or C99 does not have pipes. But POSIX and Linux (and MacOSX) have them. So you should at least edit your question to add some tags

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yeah..sorry I had no idea about that

Comment: `nanomsg` may be interesting to you... http://tim.dysinger.net/posts/2013-09-16-getting-started-with-nanomsg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent needs to close its side of the pipe to the child so that the child will detect end-of-file and terminate.

```
  while(fgets(buffer,255,stdin)!=NULL)
      fprintf(output,"%s",buffer);
  fclose(output); // does close(fd[1]);
  FILE *input = fdopen(fd2[0],"r");
  while(fgets(buffer,255,input)!=NULL)
    printf("Parent: %s",buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you now there is no more deadlock!! But the output is gibberish...any idea why?

Comment: Oh okay...I am super tired and I did close(fd[0]) instead of fclose(output). Thanks sir, you are like a debugging ninja

Answer (score 2):

When you have both input and output pipes between two (single-threaded) processes, you can have some [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), so you need to have an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using a multiplexing syscall (generally [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) and you will either read or write, depending on what is possible. Of course you need to buffer! BTW, in that case, you'll better use low level [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) without using `<stdio.h>` (and if you still do use `stdio`, don't forget to [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)....). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

<sup>(of course I am supposing a POSIX or Linux system)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure everything gets closed.  After

```
dup2(fd[0],fileno(stdin));
```

you should do:

```
close(fd[0]);
```