# if send() returns x bytes, does recv() get the same amount of bytes in one call?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, posix

I'm aware of the need to call send() in a loop until the desired amount of bytes have been sent. Also on the receiving side.

Here is a part of wrapper around recv I wrote:

```
do{
            result = socket->receiveData(m_recvBuf + recv_len , BUF_LENGTH - recv_len);
            recv_len += result;
.....
```

I'm a little confused about couple of things, so here goes:

1. if the send() returns 10 bytes, are those ten bytes still only at the sender side, but ready to be sent. Or have the bytes physically arrived to the receiver computer?
2. If the answer to the above is yes, does then calling recv() always return those 10 bytes as they have already arrived?
3. I could also put it this way; if send has been called three times each time returning 10, so total bytes sent supposedly being 30. Does then calling recv(), one time, return 30 bytes?

Question 1. edited as "still only at the receiver side" should be "still only at the sender side".

Scenario: 
My program in pc1 calls send();
send() returns 1;
My code things that one byte has been sent to the receiver program in pc2.
The network cable got eaten by a dog the moment after my send() function returned 1.

If that is the case in real life, I surely have misunderstood the benefits of TCP vs UDP.

Thanks all for giving time in answering.

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocols. There are no packets and no boundaries. A `recv` call may "receive" less than a single `send` call, or it may get data from multiple `send` calls.

Comment: ^^^^^ it's possible, but unlikely, that in your example it would take 30 recv() calls, each returning one byte, to get the 30 bytes.  You should code to ensure that such an unlikely scenario is handled correctly.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding a little bit. I know this is a streaming protocol and I know each send/receive can send "whatever" many bytes. As seen in my code snippet I have programmed around "split packages". That is not at all I'm asking about.
Please read the questions carefully and see if you have answers to them.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot. What kind of application are you coding? Give additional motivation and context. Show, if possible, some [MCVE]. So add a few paragraphs to your question!

Comment: And your dog eating the cable is probably an issue for robotic microsurgery, but probably not for a game server. In some cases, you just reason at the application software level, in other cases you want to reason at the system of systems level: for remote robotic brain microsurgery, you certainly also take care of the remote robot, of the network, etc... And -for neural surgery robots- you probably want to estimate the probability of failure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the send() returns 10 bytes, are those ten bytes still only at the
>   sender side, but ready to be sent. Or have the bytes physically
>   arrived to the receiver computer?

You cannot tell where the 10 bytes are exactly, some of them can be waiting somewhere in the sending machine, some over some wire and some waiting somewhere in the receiving machine.

> If the answer to the above is yes, does then calling recv() always
>   return those 10 bytes as they have already arrived?

N/A

> I could also put it this way; if send has been called three times each
>   time returning 10, so total bytes sent supposedly being 30. Does then
>   calling recv(), one time, return 30 bytes?

You cannot tell! The only thing you can say, in TCP mode, is that bytes are received in the same order that they have being sent.

> Scenario: My program in pc1 calls send(); send() returns 1; My code
>   things that one byte has been sent to the receiver program in pc2. The
>   network cable got eaten by a dog the moment after my send() function
>   returned 1.

Then you cannot say anything...

If that is the case in real life, I surely have misunderstood the benefits of TCP vs UDP.

UDP is datagram-oriented semantic, like postal sytem (no preserved order, no guaranty of any kind, loss is possible, duplicate, etc)

TCP is stream-oriented semantic, like phone system (preserved order and no loss).

Of course in case of hard network failure, TCP cannot ensure anything!

As TCP is build on top of IP (datagram) what is sent over TCP is fragmented to be sent via IP, and you don't control such fragmentation (I forgot to tell about caching, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try:

1. You don't know. All that is known is that the network stack has accepted the data, and will do its best to transfer it.
2. N/A
3. No, there are no such guarantees. TCP/IP is stream-oriented, it's two streams of bytes with no further structure (messages, packets, writes, frames, whatever). You must make sure your data serialization format supports finding the message boundaries so the receiver can interpret the data.

Comment: Thanks for good answer! Just to clarify further.
1. If a single send() returns e.g. 10, and it is not physically gone through the network, can then the network stack send those 10 bytes in multiple chunks? That is, the return values from the send() does not necessarily being the same as what recv() returns respectively?

3. I'm fully aware  of that thanks :)

Comment: Just a thought... I always thought that if the send() returns a number that would be a confirmation on those number of bytes had been safely sent over the network. If that is not the case, doesn't that defy the purpose of how tcp/ip is supposed to work, e.g. vs UDP? Does the network stack not wait for some kind of ACK from the receiver to confirm that x number of bytes have arrived before the send() can return how many bytes it has sent?

Comment: @Ipraks you should read up on how the TCP windowing protocol works.  If the sending end had to wait for a specific ACK to every send() call, the transfer rate would be very slow and very dependent upon route latency.

Answer (score 1):

> if send() returns x bytes, does recv() get the same amount of bytes in one call?

In general, certainly **no** !!

For example, for [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)/IP sockets (see [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) & [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)) going through wifi routers and/or intercontinental routers, packets could be fragmented and/or reassembled. So a given `send` can correspond to several `recv` and vice versa, and the "boundaries" of messages are not respected. Hence, for applications, TCP is a *stream of bytes* without any message boundaries. Read also about [sliding window protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol) and [TCP congestiion control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) used inside TCP.

In practice, you might observe, e.g. between two computers on the same Ethernet cable, that packets are not fragmented or reassembled. But you should *not* code with that hypothesis.

Concretely, application level protocols like [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) or [JSONRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) or [X11 protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) should be designed to define message boundaries and **both server and client sides should do buffering**.

You'll want to use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

> if the send() returns 10 bytes, are those ten bytes still only at the receiver side, but ready to be sent.

It is not easy to define what "being still at the reciever side" really means (because you don't really care about what happens inside the kernel, or inside the network controller, or on intercontinental cables). Therefore the above sentence is meaningless.

Your application code should only care about [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) and related, [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) and related, [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [accept(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html), [connect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html), [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) etc...

You might want to use messaging libraries like [0mq](http://zeromq.org/).

> The network cable got eaten by a dog the moment after my send() function returned 1.

Why do you care that much about such a scenario. Your dog could also have dropen your laptop, or have pee-ed on it. Once `send` has told your application than ten bytes have been emitted, you should trust your kernel. But the receiving program might not yet have gotten these bytes (on another continent, you'll need to wait dozens of milliseconds, which is a quite big delay for a computer). Very probably, the ten bytes are in the middle of the ocean when your dog have bitten your Ethernet cable (and you can *reasonably* code as if they have been emitted).
The TCP protocol will detect that the link has been interrupted, but that error would be given to your program much later (perhaps as an error for the *next* call to `send` happening ten seconds after).

<sup>(there are some large macroscopic delays in the TCP definition, perhaps as large as 128 seconds -I forgot the details- and these delays are too small for interplanetary communication; so TCP can't be used to Mars)</sup>

You should (most of the time) simply reason at the system call level.

<sup>(of course, in some cases -think of remote neurosurgical robots- that might not be enough)</sup>

> I surely have misunderstood the benefits of TCP vs UDP.

If you just used UDP, a given packet could be fragmented, lost or received *several* times. With TCP, that cannot reasonably happen (at least when the *next* packets have been successfully sent and received).

Comment: Thanks for good answer. Could you comment on unwinds answer nr. 1? It's regarding whether the send() function returns number of bytes it is going to send, or actual bytes physically on the other end of the network.

Comment: It should be "at the sender side"... If that clarifies what i mean.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario, and I believe you don't understand TCP/IP (which do have some ACK). IMHO, you should not care about your scenario. Your question in the comment is at the wrong level of abstraction.

Comment: If send() returns 1 you think you have sent one byte, agree? Are you telling me that you can not be certain the receiver has got that one byte?

Comment: I'm telling you that you need to **improve your question a big lot** and give much more context and motivation. Is your application life-critical? What certainty do you need? How much efforts (and money spending) can you afford?

Comment: Ok, ill try. And no its not life critical :)

Comment: You won't put the same efforts on a remote neurosurgical robot and on just a gaming server. That is why context and motivation are relevant!

Comment: True, but seeking knowledge and doing things the right way is relevant even though you are programming just a gaming server. One might be programming neurosurgical robot in the future ;)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll program game servers and neurosurgical robots in the same way (please don't). Programming is about trade-offs (and you don't make the same ones in these cases).

Comment: @Ipraks: if send returns 1, it means that the kernel has accepted 1 byte to send. So it doesn't mean that the receiver side got this one byte. It only means that the kernel will send it. When the receiver gets this one byte, it will at some point send back an ACK. But I'm not sure whether is possible to get this info about ACK-arrival in user space. Perhaps not. So if you need to make sure that a data has arrived, the receiver side need to send back some information about this.

Comment: Thanks @geza for a good non arrogant answer :) This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't forget also the network itself: an intercontinental cable might keep a kilobyte of data in packets....

Answer (score 0):

my motto: "if in doubt, try it out".

This is a complete program that demonstrates that on my machine, an entire packet of one million bytes does not even make it through the loopback adapter without being buffered into separate reads (and possibly writes, as I have used the composite function `asio::write()` :

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using boost::system::error_code;
}

using protocol = asio::ip::tcp;

struct event
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool notified = false;

    void notify()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
        notified = true;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return this->notified; });
    }
};

struct emitter
{
    emitter(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}

    template<class...Ts>
    void operator()(Ts&&...ts)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
        auto emit_item = [&os = this->os](auto&& x)
        {
            os << x;
        };
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand { 0,
            (emit_item(ts),0)...
        });
        os << std::endl;
    }

    std::ostream& os;
    std::mutex m;
};

event rx_ready;
emitter stdout_emit { std::cout };

void sender()
{
    asio::io_service executor;

    auto big_buffer = std::vector<char>(1000000, 'a');
    protocol::socket sock(executor);
    rx_ready.wait();
    asio::error_code ec;
    if(sock.connect(protocol::endpoint(asio::ip::address_v4(0x7f000001), 12345)), ec) {
        stdout_emit("connect failure: ", ec.message());
        return;
    }
    auto written = asio::write(sock, asio::buffer(big_buffer), ec);
    stdout_emit("wrote: ", written);
    if (ec) {
        stdout_emit("write failure: ", ec.message());
    }
    sock.shutdown(protocol::socket::shutdown_send, ec);
    if (ec) {
        stdout_emit("shutdown failure: ", ec.message());
    }
    sock.close(ec);
    if (ec) {
        stdout_emit("close failure: ", ec.message());
    }
}

void start_receiving(protocol::socket& s)
{
    auto huge_buffer_ptr = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(1000000);

    s.async_read_some(asio::buffer(*huge_buffer_ptr), [huge_buffer_ptr, &s](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t size)
    {
        stdout_emit("read ", size, " bytes");
        if (ec)
        {
            stdout_emit("read error: ", ec.message());
        }
        else
        {
            start_receiving(s);
        }
    });
}

void receiver()
{
    asio::io_service executor;
    protocol::acceptor acceptor(executor);
    auto ep = protocol::endpoint(protocol::v4(), 12345);
    acceptor.open(ep.protocol());
    acceptor.bind(ep);
    acceptor.listen();

    protocol::socket s(executor);
    acceptor.async_accept(s, [&](asio::error_code ec){
        if (ec) {
            stdout_emit("accept: ", ec.message());
        }
        else
        {
            start_receiving(s);
        }
    });
    rx_ready.notify();
    executor.run();
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::thread(receiver);

    sender();

    t.join();
}
```

sample results:

```
read 393216 bytes
wrote: 1000000
read 606784 bytes
read 0 bytes
read error: End of file

Process finished with exit code 0
```

changing the read and write buffers to 10,000,000 bytes gave me this:

```
read 393216 bytes
read 638820 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 638820 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 638820 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 638820 bytes
wrote: 10000000
read 639028 bytes
read 639028 bytes
read 22196 bytes
read 0 bytes
read error: End of file

Process finished with exit code 0
```