# grep, tee, and sleep not playing nice together

Tags: bash, grep, tee

```
(echo foo && sleep 1 && echo bar) | grep -P . | tee /dev/null
```

The above code is the smallest case of my problem I could come up with. The expected behavior is that `foo` would be echo'd, a second would pass, then `bar` would be echo'd.

What actually happens is that a second passes then `foo` and `bar` are echo'd at the same time. If you remove *either* the `grep` or the `tee` command (or both, obviously) the correct behavior happens. But with them together it does not.

I assume this is some kind of buffering issue, but I don't know how to get around it. The actual script this is taking place in for me is running for quite a while and I'm not seeing any log messages till the very end. Halp! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: force exec'd process to have unbuffered stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout)

Comment: By 'correct' and 'expected', you mean 'desired'.  The behavior you see is both correct and expected.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 5):

Etan's comment prompted me to look through grep's man page and I found the `--line-buffered` flag. Adding that fixed the problem

```
(echo foo && sleep 1 && echo bar) | grep --line-buffered -P . | tee /dev/null
```