# Writing Chrome/V8 --trace-gc output to a file - stdout redirection does not work

Tags: google-chrome, garbage-collection, chromium, v8

We are working on an automated system for memory performance monitoring.

We start Chrome with proper flags `--trace-gc --trace-gc-verbose` both on Windows7 and MacOSX High Sierra.

The output is printed and visible on the console. However capturing the output with standard stream redirection **does not work**:

What do we do:

MacOS X:
`﻿﻿./Google\ Chrome --js-flags="--trace-gc --trace-gc-verbose" > log.txt 2>&1`

Windows:
`chrome --no-sandbox --js-flags="--trace_gc --trace_gc_verbose" > log.txt 2>&1`

What gets written into the log file is only a part of what you can see on the screen: all gc-related data is missing in the file although abundant in the terminal window (you can see all the data when you run the app without stream capture at all).

We suppose a new process for V8 is run and it's output is not directed to stdout, though somewhat it gets printed to the console itself.

The V8 C++ code shows no mark of such a strange redirect, pretty clean standard code, in fact one can record gc-output of `node --trace-gc script.js` without any problem with standard stdout/stderr. It seems Chrome adds the undesired behavior.

**Question** how to record Chrome gc-related data to a file both on Windows and MacOS X.

**Partial, unacceptable solution** on POSIX-based systems we can grab all the terminal output with `script` command. The dump contains all the data we need, but the solution does not cover Windows scenario (we do need tests on Windows) and in fact it does not solve the problem neither explains the reason behind the lacking data, it simply hides the problem away.

Comment: Done up-voting :)

Comment: It seems to be realted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout I'll update on the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things worth being pointed out.

1. The only output that is actually being redirected is Chrome-related. I mean if we redirect stderr to a file we can see the errors in this file, but only Chrome's errors not V8's.
2. I wanted to use `script` command as I tried Powershell `Start-Transcript`, `Tee` and a few other options. It has turned out (no suprises here) that Windows has no command that can be used to achieve desired effect (AFAIK). So I used Babun (http://babun.github.io/) which is basically preconfigured Cygwin. No GC log has been displayed. Only Chrome's related stuff. I think that V8's logs are not being forwarded to Cygwin.

UPDATE:
This issue may be somehow related with these:

1. Chrome spawns many processes and from what I can see from logs - GC logs are gathered from child process (different PID than one related with opened terminal window). I do not know how this alone could affect STDOUT redirection. It's just a fact I noticed.
2. I found out that an application may know if its STOUD is being redirected and handle this situation differently - e. i. using buffers without flushing when STDOUT is being redirected to a file but not if it is printed on the console.

UPDATE:
I have created a following bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=865876#c3

It seems like it was noticed and someone is going to take care of it.

UPDATE:
It seems like ChromeDriver can do exactly what we need - http://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging/performance-log
Another workaround would be to run Chrome with `--enable-precise-memory-info` and the periodically invoke `window.performance.memory`, but that command does not provide us with nearly as much data as ChromeDriver

Comment: From the bug report: "On Windows Chrome is set as GUI application with no terminal window. If you would like to see Chrome's logs in the terminal you can use EditBin.exe: `EditBin /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE chrome.exe`"