# Redirect program output to file and file content preview

Tags: bash

I am running a Python script on Linux bash. The script prints output from time to time. I want to:

- redirect script output to file
- run it in background
- have ability to `tail -f` the results in the file while the script is running

I want to use tail -f only from time to time to monitor progress in some long process. I don't know why but after I redirect output I see no content in the file while the process is still running. Full content appears in the file after Python script ends.

Comment: So....do that.  What's the question?  Are you just looking for : `script > file & tail -f file`?

Comment: Or perhaps buffering is an issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I want to use tail -f only from time to time to monitor progress in some long process. I don't know why but after I redirect output I see no content in file while process is still running. Full content appears in file after Python script ends.

Comment: `man python`: _`-u`     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered._ Would that work?

Comment: Buffering was my problem. I applied this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375. ```python3 -u script.py``` solution also works.

Comment: Related: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: Other possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3332045/8344060