# Why does this command pipe prints nothing on Debian or Mac?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, grep, ping

This command prints the milliseconds till g.co ten times per second:

```
ping -i 0.1 g.co | grep ms
```

If I add just another grep it no longer prints anything ever (both on Mac and on Debian):

```
ping -i 0.1 g.co | grep ms | grep m
```

Why is that?

```
yes | grep y | grep y
```

This does print an infinite series of y lines as expected

Comment: Try `grep --line-buffered ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait for some time. mac os waits for the buffer to fill up before printing the whole block.

If you do want immediate line-by-line output, you can add the "--line-buffered" flags to both grep commands, effectively making your command -

> ping -i 0.1 g.co | grep ms --line-buffered | grep m --line-buffered

For more details, refer to this other question -
[bash: force exec'd process to have unbuffered stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout)