# Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?

Tags: bash, shell, colors, terminal, redirect

Various bash commands I use -- fancy diffs, build scripts, etc, produce lots of color output.

When I redirect this output to a file, and then `cat` or `less` the file later, the colorization is gone -- presumably b/c the act of redirecting the output stripped out the color codes that tell the terminal to change colors.

Is there a way to capture colorized output, including the colorization?

Comment: lol @ the dupe notice: "_How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe_" really seems to the same question as "_Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?_"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

One way to capture colorized output is with the `script` command.  Running `script` will start a bash session where all of the raw output is captured to a file (named `typescript` by default).

Comment: An example: `script -q /dev/null ls | cat`

Comment: This causes the resulting file to contain color codes (of course); is there any way to then print the file in a way that makes use of the color codes and properly displays the colors in the terminal? I tried `echo -e $(< filename)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ....actually, `echo -e $(< filename )` *does* seem to colorize output, but for some reason the first part of the output seems to be obscured by `Script done on <DATE>`.

Comment: There's a script called `ansi2html` that does an OK job of converting the resulting typescript to HTML.

Comment: another example: 
`script<enter for new shell>
lolcat /etc/motd > /tmp/color_motd`
Then edit the `typescript` file and strip out the start and end output as needed.

Comment: `script` does not work piping to interactive commands like `less`, unless you add more complicated redirects. It's easier to use `unbuffer` https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410273

Comment: If you need to it can be then made into a pdf with https://stackoverflow.com/a/22528648/4288043

Comment: less -R will let you view colors.

Comment: The `script` command is unavailable in Git Bash for Windows

Answer (score 51):

Redirecting doesn't strip colors, but many commands will detect when they are sending output to a terminal, and will not produce colors by default if not.  For example, on Linux `ls --color=auto` (which is aliased to plain `ls` in a lot of places) will not produce color codes if outputting to a pipe or file, but `ls --color` will.  Many other tools have similar override flags to get them to save colorized output to a file, but it's all specific to the individual tool.

Even once you have the color codes in a file, to see them you need to use a tool that leaves them intact.  `less` has a `-r` flag to show file data in "raw" mode; this displays color codes.  *edit:* Slightly newer versions also have a -R flag which is specifically aware of color codes and displays them properly, with better support for things like line wrapping/trimming than raw mode because less can tell which things are control codes and which are actually characters going to the screen.

Comment: `ls --color` is the same as `ls --color=always` - you're thinking of `ls --color=auto`

Comment: ⁺¹, you just solved our discuss about whether it is the application determines was it redirected to file, or is it the shell itself when does redirect takes care of stripping the color ANSI symbols.

Answer (score 40):

Inspired by the other answers, I started using `script`. I had to use `-c` to get it working though. All other answers, including `tee`, different `script` examples did not work for me.

Context:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- running behavior tests with `behave` and starting shell command during the test with python's `subprocess.check_call()`

Solution:

```
script --flush --quiet --return /tmp/ansible-output.txt --command "my-ansible-command"
```

Explanation for the switches:

- `--flush` was needed, because otherwise the output is not well live-observable, coming in big chunks
- `--quiet` supresses the own output of the script tool
- `-c, --command` directly provides the command to execute, piping from my command to script did not work for me (no colors)
- `--return` to make script propagate the exit code of my command so I know if my command has failed

Comment: Best answer! Thanks.

Comment: I love that it even works with arguments. To suppress terminal output while still writing to the file, add `> /dev/null` to the end of the command (`script --flush --quiet --return /tmp/ansible-output.txt --command "my-ansible-command"
> /dev/null`).

Comment: Add `-a` flag to append to log file.

Answer (score 19):

I found that using `script` to preserve colors when piping to `less` doesn't really work (less is all messed up and on exit, bash is all messed up) because less is interactive. `script` seems to really mess up input coming from `stdin` even after exiting.

So instead of running:

```
script -q /dev/null cargo build | less -R
```

I redirect `/dev/null` to it before piping to less:

```
script -q /dev/null cargo build < /dev/null | less -R
```

So now `script` doesn't mess with `stdin` and gets me exactly what I want. It's the equivalent of `command | less` but it preserves colors while also continuing to read new content appended to the file (other methods I tried wouldn't do that).

Comment: By the way, `script` doesn't exit as long as the pipeline is running.  So in your first command above (actually both of them), it doesn't exit until `less` does.

Comment: This is great. A major use case for me is reading colored `grep` output that's taller than the height of my screen, which doesn't really make sense except with a reader like `less` that can let me scroll coherently.

Comment: any idea on how to get this to work with shell functions? it doesn't seem to work with them. I get command not found or nothing.

Comment: @MrE No because `script` is an executable so it doesn’t have access to your shell functions. You need to wrap them in standalone scripts.

Comment: It's easier to use `unbuffer`, which works when piping to `less` and other interactive commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410273

Comment: The command works like a charm `script -q --return /dev/null < /dev/null | ls -alh`

Answer (score 12):

some programs remove colorization when they realize the output is not a TTY (i.e. when you redirect them into another program). You can tell some of those to use color forcefully, and tell the pager to turn on colorization, for example use `less -R`

Answer (score 6):

[This question](https://superuser.com/a/751809/280656) over on superuser helped me when my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38071740/1999993) (involving `tee`) didn't work.  It involves using `unbuffer` to make the command think it's running from a shell.

I installed it using `sudo apt install expect tcl` rather than `sudo apt-get install expect-dev`.

I needed to use this method when redirecting the output of `apt`, ironically.

Answer (score -4):

I use `tee`: pipe the command's output to `tee`*`filename`* and it'll keep the colour.  And if you don't want to see the output on the screen (which is what `tee` is for: showing and redirecting output at the same time) then just send the output of `tee` to `/dev/null`:

*`command`*`| tee`*`filename`*`> /dev/null`

Comment: What is the version of `tee` you are using for that? `tee 8.21` (shipped with Ubuntu 14.04) does not seem to colorize output by default (tested with cmake + make in a dummy program).

Comment: I've just tested it on two machines, one with tee 8.21 and one with tee 8.25.  Both worked.  I did `echo "^[[32mhello^[[0m" | tee temp.txt > /dev/null` (where `^[` is the escape character) and then checked `temp.txt` using `cat` and using `od -c`.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? A program can only tell that it's emitting content to a FIFO -- it can't tell if that FIFO has `tee` or any other specific program behind it. Thus, *if* that program is configured to emit color only direct to a TTY, a pipeline to `tee` will disrupt it as much as a pipeline to any other program.

Comment: This isn't a theoretical answer: I have used it successfully!  I don't know how it works, but it does for me where a simple redirect fails.

Comment: this definitively does not work for the purpose of the question. This works only when directly echoing the colors as said in the comments above as that does not check if the terminal is color capable but just echoes whatever is asked to. `tee` does change the terminal and affects programs which check it the terminal is interactive the same way as a simple direct does.