# Capturing colorized output to a bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, colors

I want to capture the color output from `git status` in a variable and print it later.

So far I have come up to:

```
status=$(git status -s)
echo -e "$status"
```

The above script keeps the newline intact (thx to [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613572/146272)) but strips the color from the output.

**Is there a way to keep the color in the variable and echo it?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not that bash strips the color output before storing the text, but that `git` refuses to produce the colored output int he first place, probably because it can tell that its STDOUT is not a terminal. Many commands do this (e.g. `ls`). Most of these have an option telling them to use color anyway, for use in precisely this situation (e.g. `--color` for `ls`). Consult your `git` documentation whether it also has such an override option.

Comment: For me, I needed to change `color.status` to always, not `color.ui`.

Answer (score 6):

For a git-specific solution, you can force git to provide color via the `color.status` configuration option. To override the configuration entry for this single command, use `git -c color.status=always status`.

Remember that command output captured this way doesn't necessarily include the trailing newline so you'll want to add that if you plan on printing it later.

```
out=$(git -c color.status=always status)
printf "$out\n"
```

For a more generic solution that works with other programs that don't provide color overrides, a better way to do it is with script as shown at [Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect)

In those cases, you would want to use `status=$(script -q /dev/null git status | cat)`

Answer (score 3):

As Kilian Foth mentioned:

> "Consult your git documentation whether it also has such an override option"

Git documentation says (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git):

> "if you want color codes in your redirected output, you can instead pass a --color flag to the Git command to force it to use color codes"

Using git version 1.9.2, I am trying "git status --color" and "git --color status" but none of them seem to have that flag valid. May be is not yet implemented?

However, capturing the colored output of `ls` works with this:

```
IFS=""
output=$(ls -l --color)
echo -e "$output"
```