# bash command preserve color when piping

Tags: bash, colors, pipe, xterm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect)

### setup

In this case specifically I'm trying to preserve the colors in `git status -s` when piping it to another command.

Some git commands, `diff` for instance, and other commands like `grep` have an option `--color=always` but `git status` does not.

### question

Is there a way to pipe or capture the output of a command and make it think it is outputting to the xterm shell so it doesn't automatically disable colors?

Comment: I would say the easiest way is to pass a configuration paramter like: git -c 'color.ui=always' status | more -R

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a `script` snippet using the colorized output of `ls` as an example (on Mac OS X 10.6).

```
# no colored ls output if stdout is a pipe (and not a tty)
ls -G /
ls -G / | cat
script -q /dev/null ls -G / | tr -d '\r' | cat

# write output of script command to a variable
var="$(script -q /dev/null ls -G / | tr -d '\r' | cat)"
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Isn't this a lot easier?  http://serverfault.com/a/26521/50948

Comment: @paradroid - Easier for "ls", but some programs might not have an option to force coloring.

Comment: [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)?

Comment: Using your example, how would I save the return code(`$?`) of `ls -G`?

Comment: The `-e` option of script makes the return code carry over.

Comment: Why do you use `tr -d '\r'`

Answer (score 7):

Most commands that do print out those color codes explicitly check if stdout/stderr is a tty (using the [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function).

If you want to preserve the color codes, you can run it within a terminal emulator like `screen` or the direct logger `script`, saving the output to a file.

Comment: can the `script` command be told to write to a variable?

Comment: @rennat you can save to a temporary file and then read from the file into a variable.