# How to get subprocess' stdout data asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, stdout, subprocess

I wrote a simple python script for my application and predefined some fast commands like make etc.

I've written a function for running system commands (linux):

```
def runCommand(commandLine):
    print('############## Running command: ' + commandLine)
    p = subprocess.Popen(commandLine, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    print (p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Everything works well except a few things:

- I'm using *cmake* and it's output is colored. Any chances to save colors in output?
- I can look at output after process has finished. For example, *make* runs for a long period of time but I can see the output only after full compilation. How to do it asynchronously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure about colors, but here's how to poll the subprocess's stdout one line at a time:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmake', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while proc.poll() is None:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print output
```

Don't forget to read from stderr as well, as I'm sure cmake will emit information there.

Answer (score 4):

You're not getting color because `cmake` detects if its stdout is a terminal, if it's not it doesn't color its own output. Some programs give you an option to force coloring output. Unfortunately `cmake` does not, so you're out of luck there. Unless you want to patch `cmake` yourself.

Lots of programs do this, for example grep:

```
# grep test test.txt
test
 ^
 |
 |------- this word is red
```

Now pipe it to cat:

```
# grep test test.txt | cat
test
 ^
 |
 |------- no longer red
```

`grep` option `--color=always` to force color:

```
# grep test test.txt --color=always | cat
test
 ^
 |
 |------- red again
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding how to get the output of your process before it finishes, it should be possible to do that replacing:

```
p.stdout.read
```

with:

```
for line in p.stdout:
```

Regarding how to save colored output, there isn't anything special about that. For example, if the row output is saved to a file, then next time `cat <logfile>` is executed the console will interpret the escape sequences and displaye the colors as expected.

Comment: with `readline()` I have a numbers in row instead of text, what's wrong?

Comment: @Ockonal Actually if you use the for loop, there's no need to use `readline`.  You can find an example of both strategies [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2804543/183066).

Comment: Actually `for line in p.stdout` is not good in Python 2 according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line#comment11236752_2813530

Answer (score 1):

For CMake specifically, you can force color output using the option `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1`:

```
command = 'make CLICOLOR_FORCE=1'
args = shlex.split(command)
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then print as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977796/8807809):

```
while proc.poll() is None:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

If you decode to utf-8 before printing, you should see colored output.
If you print the result as a byte literal (i.e. without decoding), you should see the escape sequences for the various colors.

Consider trying the option `universal_newlines=True`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

This causes the call to `proc.stdout.readline()` to return a string instead of a byte literal so you can/must skip the call to `decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

To do async output do something like: http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/440554

Not sure if you can capture the coloured output. If you can get the escaped colour codes you may be able to.

Comment: If we get the colour codes the terminal will translate them. The problem is though, most application distinguish between being attached to a terminal or being piped into another application. The only way to convince these applications to still produce the colour codes is by faking that the receiving app (in this case our python process) is in fact a tty and not a pipe. A task much easier said than done...

Answer (score -1):

Worth noting here is the use of the `script` command as a pseudo terminal and be detected as a tty instead of redirect(pipe) file descriptor, see:
[bash command preserve color when piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641392/bash-command-preserve-color-when-piping/7646881#7646881)

Works like a charm...

As per the example in the question simply let `script` execute `cmake`:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('script cmake', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while proc.poll() is None:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print output
```

This tricks `cmake` into thinking it's being executed from a terminal and will produce the ANSI candy you're after.

nJoy!