# Stopping nodejs service does not kill node process when wrapped in "script" command

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, init

I am running a [turnkey-node](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/nodejs) (Debian Wheezy) appliance in VirtualBox on a Windows XP 32-bit host.

Within the Debian guest I've made a few modifications so that it runs my own NodeJS application rather than the default one.

I've also modified the example `run.sh` script so that instead of directly running `node`, it runs the [`script`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) command which in turn runs `node` so that I can log its output to a file and trick node into thinking it's using a TTY so as to retain color escape sequences in the log output, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401002/386205), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515208/386205) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7641392/386205).

This all works great except when it's time to shutdown the nodejs service -- the `script`, `sh` and `node` processes all continue to live on after the service is stopped.

Any ideas why this is happening? I am guessing the included [nodejs init script](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/common/blob/master/overlays/nodejs/etc/init.d/nodejs) wasn't intended to be used like this but I wouldn't know the first thing about changing it to fix this.

Here are the changes I mentioned:

- Modified `/etc/default/nodejs` to point to my own app's `run.sh`
- Modified `run.sh` so it looks like this:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  cd `dirname $0`
  script -qfc "node server.js" server.log
  ```

There were also a couple of minor modifications in order to get nodejs working with the VirtualBox shared folder feature, but that's aside the point I think.

Comment: Well, you could use the `kill` command but it's maybe not the recommended way to go.

Comment: I linked to the included init script, it itself uses `kill`, but maybe it's not `kill`ing right right thing?

Answer (score 1):

put an `exec` before your script.

When you just say "foo" in a script, the script forks off a child and runs it, then when it exits, the shell continues on to the next command. So your "init" sees the "shell" as it's child, and node is the grandchild.

If you say `exec script -qfc "node server.js" server.log`, then you're telling the shell not to fork a child, but directly execute the command and never return. That way, your init scripts will see node as it's child, and directly send node signals.

Comment: +1 sounds legit, although I'm not having any luck with this on a brand new VM, I'll have to wait until Monday to try it out on the one I've been working on.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working. I think I must have overlooked something when asking this question though, because `service nodejs status` thinks the service isn't running at all, even with the exec in front.