# Ruby - Print with color output

Tags: ruby, shell, guard

I have a ruby script ([Guardfile](https://github.com/guard/guard)) that executes a rake command.

```
guard :shell do

  watch(%r{^manifests\/.+\.pp$}) do |m|
    spec = `rake spec`
    retval = $?.to_i
    case retval
    when 0
       if spec.length > 0 then
          puts spec
          n "#{m[0]} Tests Failed!", 'Rake Spec', :pending         
       else
          puts spec
          n "#{m[0]} Tests Passed!", 'Rake Spec', :pending

       end
    end
end
```

When I run a 'rake spec' from the command line, outputs are colorized. 
How could I make it so the output of the ruby script is also colorized?

From command line:

[image]

From ruby script:

[image]

**Update**

I was able to sort-of work around the problem by using `script`

[bash command preserve color when piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641392/bash-command-preserve-color-when-piping)

```
spec = `script -q /dev/null rake spec`
```

This still has the downside of not scrolling the text in real time. While it does preserve the colors, it does not output anything until the very end.

Is there a more native way to do this that will allow for scrolling?

Comment: Try using `spec = \`rake spec --color\``

Comment: good idea, I get this error: `invalid option: --color`

Comment: Does creating a file named ".rspec" with the contents of, "--color" work?

Answer (score 2):

First, `rake spec --color` won't work, because you're passing `--color` to `rake`, and not `rspec`.

Jay Mitchell's suggestion for color should work - by putting this in your `.rspec` file:

```
--color
```

As for having "live" output, `guard-shell` has an `eager` command for this:

https://github.com/guard/guard-shell/blob/master/lib/guard/shell.rb#L37-L51

Unfortunately, `guard-shell` has 2 important shortcomings:

- it doesn't give you access to the exit code
- it doesn't properly report failures in Guard (which causes other tasks to run)

So the `eager` method of Guard::Shell is useless for our needs here.

#### Instead, the following should work:

```
# a version of Guard::Shell's 'eager()' which returns the result
class InPty
  require 'pty'

  def self.run(command)
    PTY.spawn(command) do |r, w, pid|
      begin
        $stdout.puts
        r.each {|line| $stdout.print line }
      rescue Errno::EIO
      end
      Process.wait(pid)
    end

    $?.success?
  rescue PTY::ChildExited
  end
end

# A hack so that Guard::Shell properly throws :task_has_failed
class ProperGuardPluginFailure
  def to_s
    throw :task_has_failed
  end
end

guard :shell, any_return: true do
  watch(%r{^manifests\/.+\.pp$}) do |m|
    ok = InPty.run('rake spec')
    status, type = ok ? ['Passed', :success] : ['Failed', :failed]
    n "#{m[0]} Tests #{status}!", 'Rake Spec', type
    ok ? nil : ProperGuardPluginFailure.new
  end
end
```

The above looks ideal for a new guard plugin - good idea?

Answer (score -1):

I am unfamiliar with Guardfiles.  Can you use gems?  The colorize gem is great.

https://github.com/fazibear/colorize

Install it:

```
$ sudo gem install colorize
```

Use it:

```
require 'colorize'

puts "Tests failed!".red
puts "Tests passed!".green
```

Comment: Doesn't answer OP's question but it brought me to the colorize gem, which is what _I_ wanted. :)