# Preserving color of text piped through "less" or "more"

Tags: linux

Certain commands produce text in color for readability.

I'm using Linux.  For example when I'm using `rak` or `hg diff`
the output is in color for better readability.

However when I pipe the output through `less`

```
hg diff | less
```

the colors are lost.

How do I preserve the color?

Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/124846/105002

Comment: grep --color=always pattern file[or]string | less -R

Comment: [How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/how-to-trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe)

Comment: Also [Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect)

Answer (score 52):

I believe some commands are smart enough NOT to output color if they detect that they are writing to a pipe or a file instead of to the console, since that could ruin the parsing of their output by the next program in the pipeline.

You can try forcing the programs into outputting color with their respective flags (e.g. `--color` or whatever), but it's ultimately implementation dependent if they'll honor your request or not.

GNU grep 2.27, for example, will not output color into `less` even when passing `--color` to it. But if you pass `--color=always` and pipe it into `less`, you'll be able to see the color escape codes through `less`. And then, using the `-R` flag will have `less` interpret the color escape codes.

Comment: And for `git status`, it is [`git -c color.status=always status | less -REX`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304605/1048186)

Comment: thank you. 
I had found the answer to this years ago but obviously did not read enough. I had it in my mind that -R flag for less was the solution. After changing jobs, I found it wasn't working anymore and never bothered to look into it until now. Thanks for explaining you need to use the output colour on the preceeding command before less as well as using the -R flag for less!

Answer (score 22):

Try `less -r` or (safer) `less -R`. [See the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less).

Since you probably don't want to specify that all the time:

```
export LESS=-R # Put that in a startup script like .bashrc.local
hg diff | less
```

For Mercurial, you can also use the [pager extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension).

Note: Some commands automatically turn of color output when they detect the output goes to a pipe instead of the terminal. To fix this, force color output.

For example `ls -al` will show color output but `ls -al | less -R` will not.  `ls -al --color | less -R` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you.  But this doesn't seem to work for me for some reason.  I'm on Linux Fedora.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and it works here. Does `man less` show the option?

Comment: @ZackXu you also need to use the output color option on the command you're piping into less.

Comment: @ZackXu Check the options of the command that you pipe to `less`. Some commands detect that the output is a pipe and not a terminal and decide to use plain text in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I also discovered color options on grep, for instance, --color[=never|=auto|=always] affect what happens to coloring.  =auto will see the pipe and remove colors. =always will pass the codes on through and less -R will properly render them as discussed above.

Comment: And this improves on the `grep` related section of the [5 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29215971/1394729) how exactly?