# Keep color in 'git log' when piping to 'head' (osx)

Tags: git, macos, git-log

I have the following aliases in my bashrc file.

```
alias gl="git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all"
alias glh="gl | head -n 20"
```

Both of the aliases used to print the output of git history in color. However with the update of git to `git version 2.19.1` `glh` stopped printing the output in color. `gl` still prints the output in color. Is there a way to force `git log` to keep the color even though it is piped to `head`?

OS:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G22010
```

Comment: using `--color`?

Comment: And maybe use `git log -n 20` to display 20 commits, instead of `head`.

Comment: Both ways described above worked thank you!

Comment: `--color` is better since there are other piped commands that also prevent coloring (regex manipulation in my case).

Answer (score 7):

You can either specify `--color=always` and pipe to another program which must interpret the color escape sequences, or you can get rid of the pipe to head and use `git log -n20` directly to display only the last 20 commits. (Note that the latter could give you a different result than using `head`).

Comment: (Though `-n` option is probably superior anyway) I'd add `--color=always` should come after `git log` and may not work in some other git commands. See a bit more comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304605/3577922).